# AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'find_all' Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I dont understand why do i get this error:

I have a fairly simple function:

```
def scrape_a(url):
  r = requests.get(url)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
  news =  soup.find_all("div", attrs={"class": "news"})
  for links in news:
    link = news.find_all("href")
    return link
```

Here is th estructure of webpage I am trying to scrape:

```
<div class="news">
<a href="www.link.com">
<h2 class="heading">
heading
</h2>
<div class="teaserImg">
<img alt="" border="0" height="124" src="/image">
</div>
<p> text </p>
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you looping over `news`, then calling `news.find_all()`? Presumably you meant to use `links.find_all` instead?

Comment: Also, `href` is an *attribute* of a tag, not a tagname.

Comment: Also, did you mean to only return the *first* result?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Beautiful Soup: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'find\_all'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24108507/beautiful-soup-resultset-object-has-no-attribute-find-all)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are doing two things wrong:

- You are calling `find_all` on the `news` result set; presumably you meant to call it on the `links` object, one element in that result set.
- There are no `<href ...>` tags in your document, so searching with `find_all('href')` is not going to get you anything. You only have tags with an `href` *attribute*.

You could correct your code to:

```
def scrape_a(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
    news =  soup.find_all("div", attrs={"class": "news"})
    for links in news:
        link = links.find_all(href=True)
        return link
```

to do what I think you tried to do.

I'd use a [CSS selector](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
def scrape_a(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
    news_links = soup.select("div.news [href]")
    if news_links:
        return news_links[0]
```

If you wanted to return the value of the `href` attribute (the link itself), you need to extract that too, of course:

```
return news_links[0]['href']
```

If you needed *all* the link objects, and not the first, simply return `news_links` for the link objects, or use a list comprehension to extract the URLs:

```
return [link['href'] for link in news_links]
```

Comment: @Martin Pieters: Thanks now this just gives me one link of the first div whereas I would like to have all  links(hrefs) on the page

Comment: @Imo: your code only returned the first match, which is why my answer followed suit. I've added two options for returning all link objects, or just their `href` values.

Comment: @Imo: in future, it would be helpful if you added actual and expected results to your question, a so-called [mcve]. That way it would have been immediately obvious that you wanted a list of urls, for example.