# AttributeError: 'Resultset' object has no attribute ' findAll

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to write some code that will scrape financial data from the internet and then present it as a table in table. The problem I am having is that I keep returning an error that says- AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'findAll'
I have no idea why it keeps returning this, I have tried many things to get rid of the error but it just keeps coming back. I was hoping some on here would be able to shed some light on the situation. My code is as follows:

```
    import urllib2

    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    Goog_page = 'https://uk.finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=GOOG'

    page = urllib2.urlopen(Goog_page)

    html = page.read()

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

    soup.prettify().encode('UTF-8')

    #print soup.findAll('table')

    right_table = soup.find_all('table', {'class':'yfnc_datamodoutline1'})




    A=[]
    B=[]
    C=[]
    D=[]
    E=[]
    F=[]
    G=[]
    H=[]
    I=[]
    J=[]

    def parse_string(el):
        text = ''.join(el.findAll(text=True))
        return text.strip()
    for rows in right_table:
        rows = map(parse_string, right_table.findAll('tr'))
        for cell in rows:
            data = map(parse_string, rows.findAll('td'))
            if len(data)>1:
                    A.append(data[0].find(text=True))
                    B.append(data[1].find(text=True))
                    C.append(data[2].find(text=True))
                    D.append(data[3].find(text=True))
                    E.append(data[4].find(text=True))
                    F.append(data[5].find(text=True))
                    G.append(data[6].find(text=True))
                    H.append(data[7].find(text=True))
                    I.append(data[8].find(text=True))
                    J.append(data[9].find(text=True))
```

The error I get back is: File "...", line 37, in  rows = right_table.findAll('tr') and then the error message gets printed.

I am using python 2.7 and windows 8.1

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Beautiful Soup: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'find\_all'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24108507/beautiful-soup-resultset-object-has-no-attribute-find-all)

Comment: Ok cool, thanks. I'll check that out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this section of your code:

```
data = map(parse_string, rows.findAll('td'))
if len(data)>1:
```

You either need to use a `for` loop to traverse over your `data` object or use `rows.find('td')` instead of `findAll` if you only have one `td` element.

For instance, if you want to get the text for each `<td>` and add it to a list you could:

```
data = []
for row in right_table:
    tablecells = row.findAll('td')
    for cell in tablecells:
        data.append(row.get_text().strip())
```

Comment: Yeh that makes sense. I was thinking that perhaps the problem is that I am trying to use the second findAll command to search over a list ... is there anyway to pull out all the 'td' items in a list?

Comment: I added a snippet that should append the cells to a list