# Find all the 'h2' tags that are children of a specific div with attribute 'id' and value 'column-left'

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Using BeautifulSoup, I tried the following:

```
q =  soup.div.find_all("div", { "id" : "column-left" }, "h2")
```

But this gives me the text of the `<p>` as well. I just want the h2 that are children of a specific div.

Comment: What is the "h2" supposed to be doing? The third argument is *recursive*  so you are not looking for any h2's

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham I am trying to find h2. But not just any h2s....only the h2 that are children of div with attribute 'id' and value 'column-left'

Comment: What you want is to use find then call `find_all('h2', recursive =False)` on what find returns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a recent version of BeautifulSoup (and you should) you can just use a CSS selector, which might be easier to write and maintain anyway. e.g.:

```
>>> from bs4 import beautifulsoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('<div id=column-left><h2>Header</h2><p>Paragraph</p><h2>Another header</h2><p>Another paragraph</p></div>')
>>> soup.select('div#column-left > h2')
[<h2>Header</h2>, <h2>Another header</h2>]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you accessing `soup.div`?

Try this:

```
q =  soup.find('div', { 'id' : 'column-left' }).find_all('h2')
```

Also find_all has optional parameter 'id', so you do not have to write attributes map

```
q =  soup.find('div', id='column-left').find_all('h2')
```

Comment: I get an error: AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'find_all' I found a solution but its rather long so maybe there is an better way: `q =  soup.div.find_all("div", { "id" : "column-left"})
for k in q:
    p = k.find_all("h2")
    for i in p:
        print(i.text)`

Comment: @BitByBit i edited an example, try now please. Also see this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24108507/5091346) about return types.

Comment: Yes, this worked out fine. Jaaps3's answer also works and I choose his answer over yours because using css selectors is shorter code and easier. Yet, I'd like to thank you so much :-)