# Print the name attribute of the input field

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to find the name attribute of the input field where type = name.

```
import bs4 as bs 
import urllib.request
import requests
import webbrowser
import urllib.parse

url = "http://demo.testfire.net/default.aspx"

sauce = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce,"html.parser")

form = soup.find('form')
inputs = form.find_all('input')
print(inputs.name)
```

> Error: ResultSet object has no attribute 'name'.
>   You're probably treating a list of items like a single item.
>   Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

What's wrong with the code to print the name attribute of the input field?

Comment: The error message is quite explicit here, don't you think?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Beautiful Soup: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'find\_all'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24108507/beautiful-soup-resultset-object-has-no-attribute-find-all)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace the `find_all()` method with `find()` and and then just use the attribute name to get the value. It's a `dictionary`.

```
form = soup.find('form')
inputs = form.find('input', type='text')
print(inputs['name'])
```

Another way:

```
form = soup.find('form')
inputs = form.find('input', type='text').get('name')
print(inputs)
```

The 2nd way is safer. Because if there is no `name` attribute it will return `None` but in the 1st way it will give `KeyError`.

Comment: How to specifically find the name only when the input field where type = text and not type = submit.?

Comment: @MaccenWright I have updated the code. Have a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

```
import bs4 as bs 
import requests

url = "http://demo.testfire.net/default.aspx"

sauce = requests.get(url).content  # also okay to use urllib.urlopen(url).read() by importing urllib
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce,"html.parser")

form = soup.find('form')
inputs = form.find_all('input')  # here you get single or multiple 'bs4.element.Tag' in 'bs4.element.ResultSet'
# hence you need to iterate all result as below
for elements in inputs:
    print(elements.get('name')) # you will get txtSearch and None
```

if you are sure to get only first or last tag attribute you can treat inputs as list and access element by it's index as below:

```
inputs[1].get('name')
```

and if you always need to access first element only better to follow steps provided by @MD. Khairul Basar