# BeautifulSoup cannot locate table with specific class

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Essentially, I am attempting to extract the text from the table with the given class title below. I have the rest of the code already written that extracts the text from each of the rows, so I do not need any assistance with that aspect. I just cannot seem to figure out why I am receiving this error:

```
"ResultSet object has no attribute '%s'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?" % key
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?
```

The code is:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests

header = {'User-agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; de; rv:1.9.1.5) Gecko/20091102 Firefox/3.5.5'}

url  = requests.get("http://www.jsugamecocksports.com/boxscore.aspx?path=baseball&id=4109", headers = header).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(url, 'html.parser')   
region = soup.find_all('div', {'id': 'inning-all'})
table = region.find('table', {'class': 'sidearm-table play-by-play'})
```

Comment: Well what is unclear about the error?

Comment: I should be able to extract the respective table from 'region' using find() correct?

Comment: @RickAhif: that's not really what Python is having trouble with, more with the fact that you searched for **multiple** regions with `find_all`.

Comment: The error message cannot possibly be any clearer, and there is no indication that the issue is elsewhere, so I'm voting to close this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Beautiful Soup: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'find\_all'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24108507/beautiful-soup-resultset-object-has-no-attribute-find-all)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you wrote a **`find_all` to find the region**. As a result, it generates a **set of results**, not just a single one (of course the set can contain one, zero or more results). There are two options I think:

1. If you are sure that there is only one div with that id (normally there should only be one, you can use a `find`:

   ```
   region = soup.find('div', {'id': 'inning-all'})
   table = region.find('table', {'class': 'sidearm-table play-by-play'})
   ```

   In case there are multiple ones: iterate over the founded regions, and process them separately:
2. If you are sure that there is only one div with that id (normally there should only be one, you can use a `find`:

   ```
   regions = soup.find_all('div', {'id': 'inning-all'})
   for region in regions:
       table = region.find('table', {'class': 'sidearm-table play-by-play'})
   ```

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer. I am confident that their should only be one for a given website, so I will proceed with the first implementation. Much appreciated!

Comment: @Willem do you know a way to assgn value in single variable in your answer 1 or 2

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you may approach the problem with a single [CSS selector](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
table = soup.select_one('#inning-all table.sidearm-table.play-by-play')
```

where the CSS selector would match a `table` element with `sidearm-table` and `play-by-play` classes under the element with `inning-all` id attribute value.

Use `select()` instead of `select_one()` to locate all elements matching a selector.