# Finding and storing children of roots in Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, parent-child, children

I'm trying to find and store the children `<orgname>` from the parent `<assignee>`. My code so far runs through the XML document already picking up certain other tags - I have set it up as such:

```
for xml_string in separated_xml(infile): # Calls the output of the separated and read file to parse the data
    soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_string, "lxml")     # BeautifulSoup parses the data strings where the XML is converted to Unicode
    pub_ref = soup.findAll("publication-reference") # Beginning parsing at every instance of a publication

    lst = []  # Creating empty list to append into

    with open('./output.csv', 'ab') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f, dialect = 'excel')

        for info in pub_ref:  # Looping over all instances of publication

# The final loop finds every instance of invention name, patent number, date, and country to print and append

            for inv_name, pat_num, date_num, country, city, state in zip(soup.findAll("invention-title"), soup.findAll("doc-number"), assign.find("orgname"), soup.findAll("date"), soup.findAll("country"), soup.findAll("city"), soup.findAll("state")):

                writer.writerow([inv_name.text, pat_num.text, org_name.text, date_num.text, country.text, city.text, state.text])
```

I already have this in sequence so that each invention name and patent pairs and need the organization assignee name along with it. Problem is that there are other  tags associated with things like attorneys and such organizations looking like this:

```
<agent sequence="01" rep-type="attorney">
<addressbook>
<orgname>Sawyer Law Group LLP</orgname>
<address>
<country>unknown</country>
</address>
</addressbook>
</agent>
</agents>
</parties>
<assignees>
<assignee>
<addressbook>
<orgname>International Business Machines Corporation</orgname>
<role>02</role>
<address>
<city>Armonk</city>
<state>NY</state>
<country>US</country>
</address>
</addressbook>
</assignee>
</assignees>
```

I only want the orgname under `<assignee>` tag. I've tried:

assign = soup.findAll("assignee")
org_name = assign.findAll("orgname")

But to no avail. It simply shoots out:

> "ResultSet object has no attribute '%s'. You're probably treating a
>   list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you
>   meant to call find()?" % key
>
> AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find'. You're
>   probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call
>   find_all() when you meant to call find()?

How can I add these tags and find all the orgname under assignee tags?
It seems simple but I can't get it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Beautiful Soup: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'find\_all'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24108507/beautiful-soup-resultset-object-has-no-attribute-find-all)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`assign = soup.findAll("assignee")` returns a *list* , so that's why calling `org_name = assign.findAll("orgname")` fails, you'd have to go through each element of `assign` and call it's `.findAll("orgname")`, but it seems there's only one `<orgname>` in each `<assignee>`, so there's no need to use `.findAll` instead of `.find`. Try using `.find` to each element of `assign` using list comprehension:

```
orgnames = [item.find("orgname") for item in assign]
```

Or, to directly get their texts, checking before if the `<orgname>` exists within that `<assignee>`:

```
orgnames = [item.find("orgname").text for item in assign if item.find("orgname")]
```

Comment: This should work, @Vinícius Aguiar. The only thing is that seemingly gives me a NoneType object has no attribute 'text' message after I added:

`assign = soup.findAll("assignee")` ---> `for item in assign:` --> `org = item.find("orgname")` where lastly I add `org.text` to the writerows output. Any thoughts?

Comment: Oh, you are right, that's an issue with my solution, you should add a `if org:` before `org.text`, I'll edit my answer. @HelloToEarth just edited, it should work now!

Comment: I gotcha. So what was happening is that we parsed both the tags along with the text as a list itself unless we conditioned pulling it as text from the list as we parsed?

Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: @HelloToEarth I'm glad to Help! It's just because if there's any `<assignee>` without `<orgname>`, `.find("orgname")` will return `None` to that specific object, and we can't access `.text` of `None`. Adding a `if item.find("orgname")` will make the call `item.find("orgname").text` continue the loop to the next non-None object, it's the same as `if len(item.find("orgname")) > 0`.