# BeautifulSoup validate "title" td to extract values over multiple tables

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I'm trying to crawl an old website that has no standardised output and no style/id tags on any of it's table rows, they're just displayed like this:

```html
<table BORDER="0" VALIGN="top" CELLPADDING="3" CELLSPACING="0" WIDTH="100%">
 <tr>
  <td ALIGN="left" VALIGN="top" WIDTH="175">
   <strong>Surname</strong>
  </td>
  <td valign="top">
Bloggs
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td ALIGN="left" VALIGN="top" WIDTH="175">
   <strong>Forename(s)</strong>
  </td>
  <td valign="top">
Joe
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td ALIGN="left" VALIGN="top" WIDTH="175">
   <strong>Title</strong>
  </td>
  <td valign="top">
Mr
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td ALIGN="left" VALIGN="top" WIDTH="175">
   <strong>Gender</strong>
  </td>
  <td valign="top">
Male
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td ALIGN="left" VALIGN="top" WIDTH="175">
   <strong>Occupation</strong>
  </td>
  <td valign="top">

  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td ALIGN="left" VALIGN="top" WIDTH="175">
   <strong>Date of Birth</strong>
  </td>
  <td valign="top">
13/05/12
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

The issue is, if a field doesn't exist in the db it wont even display an empty row, some extra data just gets added as an extra table between two core tables of data and there's no indicator when that happens.

My approach with Python is a little long winded but the idea was to validate the left TD as a title and grab the right TD which is the relevant data like so:

```html
title, forename, surname, gender, occupation, dob = '', '', '', '', '', ''

tbl1 = soup.findAll('table')[1]

for tr in tbl1.findAll('tr'):
    content = tr.findAll('td')
    if content[0].text.strip() == 'Title':
        title = content[1].text.strip()
    if content[0].text.strip() == 'Forename(s)':
        forename = content[1].text.strip()
    if content[0].text.strip() == 'Surname':
        surname = content[1].text.strip()
    if content[0].text.strip() == 'Gender':
        gender = content[1].text.strip()
    if content[0].text.strip() == 'Occupation':
        occupation = content[1].text.strip()
    if content[0].text.strip() == 'Date of Birth':
        dob = content[1].text.strip()

print('"' + title + '","' + forename + '","' + surname + '","' + gender + '","' + occupation + '","' + dob + '"')
```

Whenever i try to iterate over all the tables though i get:
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'findAll'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Beautiful Soup: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'find\_all'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24108507/beautiful-soup-resultset-object-has-no-attribute-find-all)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a list of headers and use `itertools.izip_longest`:

```
import itertools
import re
headers = ['title', 'forename', 'surname', 'gender', 'occupation', 'dob']
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup 
s = soup(web_data, 'lxml')
new_s = [re.sub('\n+|\t+', '', i.text) for i in s.findAll('td')]
final_data = {a:b for a, b in itertools.izip_longest(headers, [c for i, c in enumerate(new_s) if i%2 != 0])}
```

Output:

```
{'surname': u'Mr', 'title': u'Bloggs', 'dob': u'13/05/12', 'gender': u'Male', 'forename': u'Joe', 'occupation': u''}
```