# Unable to iterate through list using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am doing some experiments with Python3.6 in Mac and BeautifulSoup. I am trying to build a simple program to scrap song lyrics from a URL and store them as plain text in a single variable but I find myself unable to iterate through the html content.

This is the code that I am running:

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("http://www.metrolyrics.com/juicy-lyrics-notorious-big.html")
c = r.content

all = soup.find_all("p",{"class":"verse"})
all[0:10]

for item in all:
    print(item.find_all("p",{"class":"verse"})[0].text)
```

The last two lines of code return the `"List index out of range" Error`

Also, if I try to do `all = all.text` I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'text'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?
```

I imagine this should be something simple but don't know what to do anymore.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Beautiful Soup: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'find\_all'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24108507/beautiful-soup-resultset-object-has-no-attribute-find-all)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `item` in the loop is a BeautifulSoup tag (check it with: `type(all[0])` --> 
`<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>`).

So you can extract text directly from it:

```
for item in all:
    print(item.text)
```

And if the variable `all` is shorter than 10, it will produce an out-of-range error.

Comment: Wow, that really was simple. Thank you!