# Load a list of urls from a csv file and parse them one by one for the same data

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, beautifulsoup

I have a list of a hundred urls in a csv file. Each line in the first column has 1 url. I would like to load each url and scrape one piece of data from each.

Currently I am able to manually load a single page using beautifulsoup and the following code in order to get 'Type' and save it to a csv file:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64)     AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36'}

urldet = "http://www.someusefulhtmlpage.com/page1.html"
r = requests.get(urldet, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")

def get_txt(soup, key):
    key_tag = soup.find('span', text=re.compile(key)).parent
    return key_tag.find_all('span')[1].text
type = get_txt(soup, 'Type')

with open('someusefulhtmlpage_file.csv', 'a', newline='') as csv_file:    
 writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
 writer.writerow([type])
```

However, I have no idea where to start if I want to get a list of urls from a csv file and then parse each url with the code and save each 'Type' to a separate line in a new csv file. Any ideas?

Trying the following code but can't get it to work - I'm lost:

```
r = requests.get(all_urls, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")

all_urls = []
with open('urllist.csv') as csv_file:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    for row in reader:
        all_urls.append(row[0])
```

I see all the urls loaded but then how do I loop through each one to get the specific tag I want? Also getting an r error because r not defined...

@theausome when I add `find_all`:

```
import csv
import re
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

contents = []
with open('urllist.csv','r') as csvf: # Open file in read mode
    urls = csv.reader(csvf)
    for url in urls:
        contents.append(url) # Add each url to list contents

for url in contents:  # Parse through each url in the list.
    page = urlopen(url[0]).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
    soup.find_all('h1').contents
```

I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\alexa\Desktop\csv
>   loop 2.py", line 15, in 
>       soup.find_all('h1').contents   File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\beautifulsoup4-4.6.0-py3.6.egg\bs4\element.py",
>   line 1807, in **getattr**
>       "ResultSet object has no attribute '%s'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you
>   meant to call find()?" % key AttributeError: ResultSet object has no
>   attribute 'contents'. You're probably treating a list of items like a
>   single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

I must be missing something. I'm wondering whether it could be because I use the following code to get my tags:

```
def get_txt(soup, key):
    key_tag = soup.find('span', text=re.compile(key)).parent
    return key_tag.find_all('span')[1].text
```

and this could be conflicting with the loop?
and I also use:

`headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36'}
r = requests.get(urldet, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")`

Comment: You already show that you can loop the rows of a .csv file. Do the same thing with your .csv-file that contain your URL's and then within that loop you use beautiful soup to parse the data.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Beautiful Soup: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'find\_all'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24108507/beautiful-soup-resultset-object-has-no-attribute-find-all)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Python `csv` module to read from file and get all urls (each url is in separate line in the file) to a list and then parse.

```
import csv
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

contents = []
with open('file.csv','r') as csvf: # Open file in read mode
    urls = csv.reader(csvf)
    for url in urls:
        contents.append(url) # Add each url to list contents

for url in contents:  # Parse through each url in the list.
    page = urlopen(url[0]).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
print(soup)
```

Comment: I would like to use this method but i'm running Python 3 and don't have urllib2. Any suggestions?

Comment: I've updated code. In Python 3, you need to import `urlopen` from `urllib.request`.

Comment: ok so I manage to get this to work but I still don't understand how I can retrieve a tag from each url for example if I want to do 'soup.find('h1').text' in  each url i've loaded?

Comment: `for url in contents:` iterates through each url. So just include `soup.find('h1').contents` in the loop and it returns one result for each url. If you need all `h1` tag contents of each url, use `find_all` instead.

Comment: `find_all` returns list. It's better you go through doc than I explain it here. https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all

Comment: ok thanks I got it to work in the end. I think it's my tag finder code that was creating issues. One final question is how would be the best way to handle exceptions for example if I'm looking through an url in my list but cannot find  the relevant tag how could I move on to the next url instead of getting an error which breaks my loop and forces me to start the loop all over again?

Comment: Glad that you got it right. :) For the exception case, you may required to check what `find_all` returns. If it returns `None`, perform `continue`. This will move on to the next url. Else case, you may do whatever with the tag.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Python's `csv` module similarly to how you're writing them. Define an empty list to hold the urls and read the url csv:

```
all_urls = []
with open('<urls>.csv') as csv_file:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    for row in reader:
        all_urls.append(row[<column of url>])
```

Comment: trying your method above but can't get it to work. Maybe elaborate if possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL_filename = 'URL.csv'
URL_column_name = "Address"
data = pd.read_csv(input_filename,encoding='utf8')
weblink = (data[address_column_name]).tolist()

i=0
while i<len(weblink):
  page = request.get(weblink[i])
  Soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text,'html.parser')
  print(Soup)

  i+=1
```

Comment: Little late here but, it would help to others.