# ResultSet object has no attribute 'find_all'

Tags: python, attributeerror

i always met one problem, when I scraping one web page.

> AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

anyone can tell me how to solve this? my code as below:

```
import requests  
r = requests.get('https://www.example.com')
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')  
results = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'product-item item-template-0 alternative'})
records = []  
for result in results:  
    name = results.find('div', attrs={'class':'name'}).text 
    price = results.find('div', attrs={'class':'price'}).text[13:-11]
    records.append((name, price,))
```

I want to ask a close question.If I want to scrap multiple pages.the pattern like below,I use the code as below,but still scrap the first page only Can you solve this issue.

```
import requests  
for i in range(100):   
    url = "https://www.example.com/a/a_{}.format(i)"
    r = requests.get(url)
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')  
results = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'product-item item-template-0 alternative'})
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Beautiful Soup: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'find\_all'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24108507/beautiful-soup-resultset-object-has-no-attribute-find-all)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this. You mixed up results with result:

```
import requests  
r = requests.get('https://www.example.com')
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')  
results = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'product-item item-template-0 alternative'})
records = []  
for result in results:  
    name = result.find('div', attrs={'class':'name'}).text # result not results
    price = result.find('div', attrs={'class':'price'}).text[13:-11]
    records.append((name, price,))
```

Comment: thanks, it works, just change the results to be result.

Comment: I want to ask a close question.I want to scrap multiple pages.https://www.example.com/a/a_1     https://www.example.com/a/a_2   https://www.example.com/a/a_3  -------.I use the code as below,but still scrap the first page only Can you solve this issue.import requests  
for i in range(100):   
    url = "https://www.example.com/a/a_{}.format(i)"
    r = requests.get(url)
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')  
results = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'product-item item-template-0 alternative'})

Comment: You should post another question for this. Why are you looping 100 times?

Comment: because it has 100 pages

Comment: Oh, I see. Instead of looping 100 times, loop through the list of pages (and index it if necessary).

Comment: Can you show me the code for reference. high appreciated!

Comment: can you help answer my question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49105772/how-to-scrape-multiple-pages-from-one-site/49105813?noredirect=1#comment85222285_49105813

Answer (score 1):

Try this, remove 's' in 'results' in particularly name = **results**

your error code "name = **results**.find('div', attrs={'class':'name'}).text"

with one changes "name = **result**.find('div', attrs={'class':'name'}).text"

well, nice try!

```
import requests  
r = requests.get('https://www.example.com')
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')  
results = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'product-item item-template-0 alternative'})
records = []  
for result in results:  
    name = result.find('div', attrs={'class':'name'}).text 
    price = result.find('div', attrs={'class':'price'}).text[13:-11]
    records.append((name, price,))
```