# how to scrape multiple pages from one site

Tags: python, scrape

I want to scrap multiple pages from one site.the pattern like this：

https://www.example.com/S1-3-1.html https://www.example.com/S1-3-2.html https://www.example.com/S1-3-3.html https://www.example.com/S1-3-4.html https://www.example.com/S1-3-5.html.

I tried three method to scrape all of these pages once, but every method only scrape the first page. I show the code below, and anyone can check and tell me what  is the problem will be highly appreciated.

```
 ===============method 1====================
    import requests  
    for i in range(5):      # Number of pages plus one 
        url = "https://www.example.com/S1-3-{}.html".format(i)
        r = requests.get(url)
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')  
    results = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'product-item item-template-0 alternative'})
    ===============method 2=============
    import urllib2,sys
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    for numb in ('1', '5'):
        address = ('https://www.example.com/S1-3-' + numb + '.html')
    html = urllib2.urlopen(address).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
    results = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'product-item item-template-0 alternative'})
    =============method 3==============
    import requests 
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  
    url = 'https://www.example.com/S1-3-1.html'
    for round in range(5):
        res = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,'html.parser')
        results = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'product-item item-template-0 alternative'})
        paging = soup.select('div.paging a')
        next_url = 'https://www.example.com/'+paging[-1]['href'] # paging[-1]['href'] is next page button on the page 
        url = next_url
```

I checked some answers and checked, but it is not loop problem, please check image shown below,it is only first page results. it is really me annoyed several days
[please see photo:only first page results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QGA4.jpg),
[results picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUpAj.jpg)

Comment: In `method 1`, put the import on top and indent `soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')` and subsequent lines to execute inside the for loop

Answer (score 2):

Your indentation is out of order.

**try(Method 1)**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import requests

for i in range(1, 6):      # Number of pages plus one 
    url = "https://www.example.com/S1-3-{}.html".format(i)
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')  
    results = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'product-item item-template-0 alternative'})
```

Comment: the problem is the same, you can check the picture i showed on question content now

Comment: Can you post the error in the question instead of image?

Comment: there is no error shown, run the code and then check the result, it only scrape the first page.but we need scrape total 5 pages. that is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your page analysis should be inside the loop, like this, otherwise, it will only use one page:

```
.......
    for i in range(5):      # Number of pages plus one 
        url = "https://www.example.com/S1-3-{}.html".format(i)
        r = requests.get(url)
        from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')  
        results = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'product-item item-template-0 alternative'})
........
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you have to introduce all orders inside of the loop, otherwise, only will work with the last iteration.

Second,
You could try **closing** the requests session at the end of each iteration:

```
import requests  
    for i in range(5):      # Number of pages plus one 
    url = "https://www.example.com/S1-3-{}.html".format(i)
    r = requests.get(url)
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')  
    results = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'product-item item-template-0 alternative'})
    r.close()
```