# Python: AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

When I try to scrape a value from a website and put it into a payload request I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'get'
```

This is my code:

```
resumeURL='url'
response=self.session.get(resumeURL,headers=headers)
soup=BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

product=soup.find_all('input',{'name':'_CsrfToken', 'type':'hidden'})
payload = {
    '_CsrfToken':product.get('value')
```

When I change `find_all` to `find` I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As the error message says, `product` is `None`. `soup.find_all()` returns `None` when it doesn't find any matching elements, so that is probably the problem. A simple `print(product)` will suffice to test this hypothesis.

Comment: The _CsrfToken is definitely on the page.

Comment: Whoops, thanks @Alasdair

Comment: print(product) gives me the whole code, I am looking for the value of CsrfToken

Comment: when i print (product) i get: <input name="_CsrfToken" type="hidden" value="4b2adc0df11241b18af7b88c0e1764bd">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="firstNameInput">First name</label>
<input class="form-control" id="firstNameInput" name="firstName" placeholder="First Name" required="" type="text">
</input></div>
<div class="form-group">


How can I now get the value of _CsrfToken and put it into my payload ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Beautiful Soup: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'find\_all'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24108507/beautiful-soup-resultset-object-has-no-attribute-find-all)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken straight from the beautiful soup [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#miscellaneous):

> AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'foo' - This usually happens because you expected find_all() to return a single tag or string. But find_all() returns a *list* of tags and strings–a ResultSet object. You need to iterate over the list and look at the .foo of each one. Or, if you really only want one result, you need to use find() instead of find_all().

So if you want all the results -and not just the one- you need to iterate over all your ResultSet (e.g. `product`) and look for the `.get` of each one.
So something like:

```
for val in product:
  #check the val.get('value') for each member of list
  print val.get('value')
```

Comment: When I do
 for product in product:
     print(data.get('value'))

I get the value, however, how can I now add this to the payload?

Comment: In general, the syntax to update a dict is `dict_name[key] = "value"`, so you can do `payload[_CsrfToken] = x` where `x` is the `data.get('value')` of the ResultSet that you wish to put in the `_CsrfToken`

Answer (score 0):

I think the get method should be used in one element of the ResultSet (not on the whole set). I mean, where you do:

```
product.get('value')
```

try:

```
product[0].get('value')
```

Comment: That gives me error: TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'