# Python + BeautifulSoup for loop issue

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I've been stuck on this for a while. Can somebody please help? I'll be forever grateful!

I'm trying to pull a list of ad titles from `autotrader` and my code doesn't work.
I'm following [this](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/web-scraping-beautifulsoup/) guide.

And my code is as below:

```
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas

url = 'https://www.autotrader.co.uk/car-search?sort=sponsored&sellertype=private'
response = get(url)
html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
ad_containers = html_soup.find_all('h2', class_ = 'listing-title title-wrap')
# price_containers = html_soup.find_all('section', class_ = 'price-column')

names = []
# prices = []

for container in ad_containers:
    name = container.find_all('a', class_ ="js-click-handler listing-fpa-link").text
    names.append(name)

#for priceainers in price_containers:
#    price = price_containers.find_all('div', class_ ='vehicle-price').text
#    prices.append(price)

test_df = pandas.DataFrame({'Title': names})
print(test_df.info())
# test_df.to_csv('Autotrader_test.csv')
```

And the error message is the following:

```
C:\Users\iamcs\venv\untitled42334\Scripts\python.exe 
C:/Users/iamcs/PycharmProjects/untitled42334/hello.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/iamcs/PycharmProjects/untitled42334/hello.py", line 15, in <module>
    name = container.find_all('a', class_ ="js-click-handler listing-fpa-link").text
  File "C:\Users\iamcs\venv\untitled42334\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1807, in __getattr__
    "ResultSet object has no attribute '%s'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?" % key
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'text'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: oh of course... the error message I get: 
ResultSet object has no attribute '%s'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?" % key
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'text'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Beautiful Soup: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'find\_all'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24108507/beautiful-soup-resultset-object-has-no-attribute-find-all)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the message hints, `find_all` returns a *list* of `ResultSet` objects. Since your `container`s only have one anchor tag each, you'll want to use `tag.find` instead.

```
names = []
for container in ad_containers:
    name = container.find('a', class_="js-click-handler listing-fpa-link").text
    names.append(name)
```

Or,

```
names = [
    c.find('a', class_="js-click-handler listing-fpa-link").text
    for c in ad_containers
]
```

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({'Title': names})
df.head()
                                               Title
0                         Nissan Micra 1.2 Visia 5dr
1               Vauxhall Corsa 1.2 i 16v Comfort 3dr
2                       Vauxhall Astra 1.4 Merit 5dr
3                     Suzuki Wagon R 1.3 GL (R+) 5dr
4  Peugeot 106 1.1 INDEPENDENCE 3d 60 BHP MOT 15/...
```