# BeautifulSoup loop issues - ResultSet object has no attribute '%s

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

The code below works:

```
for i in range(0,1):
    url = "https://www.blah.com/" + get_chapter(chron_list[i])
    book = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    c = book.content
    soup = soup(c, "html.parser")
    print(soup.prettify())
```

If I change to `range(1,2)` it also works since I have two items in the `chron_list`. But when I change it to `range(0,2)` it no longer works and gives me the following error:

> "ResultSet object has no attribute '%s'. You're probably treating a
>   list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you
>   meant to call find()?" % key AttributeError: ResultSet object has no
>   attribute 'prettify'. You're probably treating a list of items like a
>   single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

I don't understand why it works for a range of one but not for a range of two. I thought maybe it was a timing issue so I added a delay of five seconds before it continued to the next iteration but that didn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Beautiful Soup: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'find\_all'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24108507/beautiful-soup-resultset-object-has-no-attribute-find-all)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You redefine `soup` within your code. After two iterations of your loop, `soup` will not refer to `BeautifulSoup` but instead to the object returned by `soup(c, "html.parser")`:

```
soup = soup(c, "html.parser")
^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Don't rename `BeautifulSoup` (or if you do, choose a different name):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

...

soup = BeautifulSoup(c, "html.parser")
```

Comment: Bingo! Thank you.