# Beautifulsoup xml parsing failure: find all returns only one result

Tags: xml, parsing, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse all datasets' IDs from xml file using beautifulsoup 
my script:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "lxml")

doc = soup.find_all('doc')
string = doc.find('str', attrs={"name":"id"})
```

Once I run it to get the string for every doc I got error:

> AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

I tried to use For loop as follow with two formats for string separately:

```
for doc in soup.find_all('doc'):

        string = doc.find_all('str', attrs={"name":"id"})
       OR
        string = doc.str
```

But it returns only one result the first one

Here is the xml text I want to parse: "doc tag repeated several times for sure"

```
<doc>
    <str name="id"></str>
    <str name="version">20110601</str>
    <arr name="access"></arr>
    <arr name="cf_standard_name"></arr><arr name="cmor_table">
    <str name="instance_id"></str>
</doc>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Beautiful Soup: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'find\_all'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24108507/beautiful-soup-resultset-object-has-no-attribute-find-all)

Answer (score 1):

In your example `soup.find_all('doc')` will return all elements  in the form of list. You need to iterate this list to find information you want.

If you want to extract specific tags inside `<doc>` tag, you can do it in various ways. I use CSS selectors, e.g. `soup.select('doc str[name="id"]')` will select all `<str>` tags with attribute `name="id"` which are inside `<doc>` tag:

```
data = """<doc>
<str name="id">1</str>
<str name="version">20110601</str>
<arr name="access"></arr>
<arr name="cf_standard_name"></arr><arr name="cmor_table">
<str name="instance_id"></str>
</doc>

<doc>
<str name="id">2</str>
<str name="version">20110602</str>
<arr name="access"></arr>
<arr name="cf_standard_name"></arr><arr name="cmor_table">
<str name="instance_id"></str>
</doc>

<doc>
<str name="id">3</str>
<str name="version">20110603</str>
<arr name="access"></arr>
<arr name="cf_standard_name"></arr><arr name="cmor_table">
<str name="instance_id"></str>
</doc>
"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pprint import pprint

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')

all_ids = [tag.text for tag in soup.select('doc str[name="id"]')]
all_versions = [tag.text for tag in soup.select('doc str[name="version"]')]

pprint([*zip(all_ids, all_versions)])
```

This example prints:

```
[('1', '20110601'), ('2', '20110602'), ('3', '20110603')]
```

Comment: I am a bit late here, but is there any way to match one <doc> id with multiple <text> tags within the same doc. Zip() won't work because the lengths of the two lists 'all_ids' and 'all_texts' are different

Comment: @SoumyaC Please open new question here on StackOverflow (with sample input and desired output) and send me a notification.

Comment: Posted a new question titled : XML parsing using BeautifulSoup : retrieve multiple text contents with same doc number inside same document