# How can I scrape all of the batters names?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests  

url = 'http://www.baseballpress.com/lineups'  

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'html.parser')  

print(soup.find('div', {'class': 'players'}).a.text)
```

This code only returned the first batter on the list. How do I get all of their names? I am new to coding so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance for your time! =)

When I tried:
print(soup.find_All('div', {'class': 'players'}).a.text)

I received this:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

When I tried:
print(soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'players'}).a.text)

I received this:
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'a'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Beautiful Soup: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'find\_all'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24108507/beautiful-soup-resultset-object-has-no-attribute-find-all)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below approach to get all the player names from that webpage. The trick here is to use the right class name connected to all the players which is in this case `player-link`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests  

url = 'http://www.baseballpress.com/lineups'  

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'html.parser')  

for names in soup.find_all(class_='player-link'):
    print(names.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

Breaking down the "find" statement:

```
print(soup.find('div', {'class': 'players'}).a.text)
```

soup.find --> return first instance of the arguments

argument 1 --> 'div' --> look for the 'div' tag

argument 2 --> dictionary with key 'class' and value 'players' --> look for the first div tag with class='players'

then calling "a.text" --> look for text in anchor tag.

just replacing "find" with "findAll" will break the "a.text" as now instead of a single tag, you are calling "a.text" on a list. Better to break the operations into 2 steps:

```
batters_div = soup.findAll('div',{"class":"players"})
for batter in batters_div:
  print(batter.a.text)
```

using list comprehension:

```
batters = [batter.a.text for batter in soup.findAll('div',{"class":"players"})]
```

Comment: … The 2nd line of code you wrote (starting with "batters_div") printed out the first batter on each team. I was hoping for all of them. I didn't know where to enter the 3rd line of code you mentioned. Thanks for your help. I am new and have a lot to learn. =)

Comment: Gotcha. I did not take a look at the actual page and its DOM... I just pointed a way to successfully call "a.text" on the results of a findAll - which is what your question seemed to be about.

Comment: Also, the third line of code is an alternate way to achieve what the first two lines did.

Comment: I am grateful for your help! Thanks again @PushkarChintaluri

Answer (score 0):

The "find" method returns only the first match.
Try "findAll" instead.

See [the documentation here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#find(name,%20attrs,%20recursive,%20text,%20**kwargs))