# ResultSet object has no attribute 'text'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item.

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, imdb

```
        from selenium import webdriver      
        from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
        from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
        from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
        from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
        import time
        from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


        #browser = webdriver.Firefox()#Chrome('./chromedriver.exe')
        YOUTUBER_HOME_PAGE_URL = "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6452574/reviews?ref_=tt_ov_rt"
        PATIENCE_TIME = 60
        LOAD_MORE_BUTTON_XPATH = '//*[@id="load-more-trigger"]' 

        driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\Panu\Dropbox\Dr.Gokhan Sir\chromedriver.exe")
        driver.get(YOUTUBER_HOME_PAGE_URL)

        while True:
            try:
                loadMoreButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="load-more-trigger"]')
                time.sleep(2)
                loadMoreButton.click()
                time.sleep(5)
            except Exception as e:
                print e
                break
        print "Complete"
        time.sleep(10)
        #Selenium hands the page source to Beautiful Soup
        soup_level1=BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

    movie_containers = soup_level1.find_all('div', class_ = 'review-container')
    print(type(movie_containers))
    print(len(movie_containers))
sample_data = movie_containers
#div = sample_data.find_all('div', class_ = 'text show-more__control')
#sample_data.text for user review and titile
reviews = []
user_titles = []
for div in sample_data:
    title = div.div.a.text
    user_titles.append(title)
    #print(div.text)
    review = div.find_all('div', class_ = 'text show-more__control').text
    reviews.append(review)
```

i got error while runing above code. AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'text'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Beautiful Soup: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'find\_all'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24108507/beautiful-soup-resultset-object-has-no-attribute-find-all)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your line:

```
review = div.find_all('div', class_ = 'text show-more__control').text
```

is causing the problem. `div.find_all` will return all divs with that class as a list object. You're then calling `.text` on that list object. How does python know which text you want to see? Iterate through your results with something like:

```
divs = div.find_all('div', class_ = 'text show-more__control')

for div in divs:
    #inside of this loop you will be accessing each review
    print(div)
    print("") #doing this to print a blank line to "separate" them for you
```

Then use the ones you want.

Comment: it gives the same error in this code divs = div.find_all('div', class_ = 'text show-more__control').text

Comment: remove the .text

Comment: @Coder my bad, you didn't need the `.text`, see the edited solution

Comment: by using this it combines all review together but i want it separate.......divs = soup_level1.find_all('div', class_ = 'text show-more__control')
data = []
for div in divs:
    review_data = div.text
    data.append(review_data)

Comment: @Coder Sorry, can you clarify a bit?

Comment: after running above code it seems that it combines all user review together but i want to separate each user review

Comment: @Coder, see my edits. Each item in that for loop called `div` is just a single review. I just printed them for your sake but you can do what you want with them there. Put them in a list, filter them, write them to a text file, it's your choice.