# python if statement text

Tags: python, if-statement, beautifulsoup

```
x =(soup.find_all('p'))
if (x.find('British dishes') != -1): 
    print ("TRUE")
else: 
    print ("FALSE")
```

Hi there, I'm newbie in `beautifulsoup`, and I am trying to print either `True` or `False` if P tag match or contains specific text.

I can print the content of the p tag, but just can't output the true or false successful. e.g. [TRUE P tag contain "British dishes"](https://www.the-ivy.co.uk/menus/)

Get me those error informations:

> ResultSet object has no attribute '%s'. You're probably treating a
>   list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you
>   meant to call find()?" % key AttributeError: ResultSet object has no
>   attribute 'find'. You're probably treating a list of items like a
>   single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

This is the text I get back from 'p' [

The Ivy welcomes customers without reservations at the central dining bar, where the A La Carte and Set menus are both served

,

Give a friend or loved one the unique experience of lunch or dinner at one of London’s most renowned restaurants

,

The Ivy's all-day menu features Ivy classics alongside modern British dishes, served daily from 12 noon until late

,

At the cocktail bar, Bar Manager Darren Ball’s cocktail lists salutes The Ivy’s history with iconic drinks from The Roaring Twenties and kitsch classics like Pina Coladas and Strawberry Daiquiris.

,

The Ivy welcomes customers without reservations at the central dining bar, where the A La Carte and Table d'hôte menus are both served.

,

To reserve a table, please call 020 7836 4751 or book online [here](https://theivy.capricebookings.com/).

,

The Ivy welcomes customers without reservations at the central dining bar, where the A La Carte and Table d'hôte menus are both served

,

For the latest updates, events and menus from London's favourite restaurants.

,

* Mandatory fields

,

We’d like to keep in touch with you about all our restaurants with exclusive news and advance booking opportunities. We will contact you about special events, new openings as well as the latest seasonal menus. We will keep your data secure, and of course would never sell or share data. You can change your mind at any time by clicking unsubscribe on any email you receive or by clicking the link on our website. For further detail on our data policy and protection.

]

Comment: No this is he error I get: "ResultSet object has no attribute '%s'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?" % key
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

Comment: can you please post your code when you are requesting the url.

Comment: Your problem is, that your `x` contains a sequence of results.

Comment: https://www.the-ivy.co.uk/menus

Comment: I'm not hungry right now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Beautiful Soup: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'find\_all'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24108507/beautiful-soup-resultset-object-has-no-attribute-find-all)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, you need to go through each `<p>` tag text with a loop, and make sure your searching for text in one case, which *can* be lowercase, since `British Dishes` and `British dishes` won't match. You are also not calling `.text` on the `<p>` elements, which won't extract the text from the tag.

**Fixed code:**

```
x = soup.find_all('p')
for y in x:
    lowercase = y.text.lower()
    if lowercase.find("british dishes") != -1:
        print("TRUE")
    else:
        print("FALSE")
```

Which now prints:

```
FALSE
FALSE
TRUE   # --> line has 'British dishes'
FALSE
FALSE
FALSE
FALSE
FALSE
FALSE
FALSE
```

Alternatively, you can just use the `in` operator, instead of `str.find()`:

```
for x in soup.find_all('p'):
    lowercase = x.text.lower()
    if 'british dishes' in lowercase:
        print ("TRUE")
    else: 
        print ("FALSE")
```

**Note:** Printing `"TRUE"` and `"FALSE"` is unnecessary when `True` and `False` are available. You can just use `print(True)` and `print(False)` instead here.

You could also wrap the search in function, and simply print out the boolean result:

```
def line_result(line, to_find):
    return to_find in line.lower()

for x in soup.find_all('p'):
    print(line_result(line=x.text, to_find='british dishes'))
```

If you want to return combine this all into one result, you could use [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) here:

```
print(any("british dishes" in x.text.lower() for x in soup.find_all("p")))
# True
```

Comment: Thanks @Roadrunner that worked, any way just to return a single TRUE or FALSE result?

Comment: @Bramji Do you mean searching for `British dishes` in all of the text combined? instead of on each line?

Comment: yeah all I want is one results either TRUE or FALSE, currently getting what you pointed out. In this example I would like to only have one TRUE be printed, if the word i was searching for was 'duck' I would like to only have FALSE printed.

Comment: @Bramji Did you try the final code snippet with `any()`?