# how do I parse info from yahoo finance with beautiful soup

Tags: beautifulsoup, yahoo-finance

I have got so far by using soup.findAll('span')

```
<span data-reactid="12">Previous Close</span>,
     <span class="Trsdu(0.3s) " data-reactid="14">5.52</span>,
     <span data-reactid="17"></span>,
     <span class="Trsdu(0.3s) " data-reactid="19">5.49</span>,
     <span data-reactid="38">Volume</span>,
     <span class="Trsdu(0.3s) " data-reactid="40">1,164,604</span>,
     ...
```

I want a tabkle that shows me

```
Open 5.49
Volume 1,164,604
```

...
I tried soup.findAll('span').text but it gives error msg:

```
ResultSet object has no attribute 'text'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?
```

this is the source:

```
https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/gxl.ax?p=gxl.ax
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Beautiful Soup: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'find\_all'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24108507/beautiful-soup-resultset-object-has-no-attribute-find-all)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Luckily the error gives us a hint:

> You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

Try one of these:

```
soup.findAll('span')[0].text
soup.findAll('span')[i].text
soup.find('span').text
```

This is a generic problem when navigating many selector systems, CSS selectors included. To operate on an element it must be a single element rather than a set. `findAll()` returns a set (array), so you can either index into that array (e.g. `[i]`) or find the first match with `find()`.

Answer (score 2):

`soup.findAll('span')` will return object/elements in `ResultSet`. You'd have to iterate through those to print the text. So try:

```
spans = soup.findAll('span')
for ele in spans:
    data = ele.text
    print(data)
```

To take your output and put into a dataframe:

```
your_output = ['Previous Close', '5.52', 'Open', '5.49', 'Bid', 'Ask', "Day's Range", '52 Week Range', 'Volume', '1,164,604', 'Avg. Volume', '660,530']

headers = your_output[::2]
data = your_output[1::2]

df = pd.DataFrame([data], columns = headers)
```

**Additional**

You certainly can use BeautifulSoup to parse and throw into a dataframe by iterating through the elements. I would like to offer an aleternative to BeautifulSoup.

Pandas does most of the work for you if it can identify tables within the html, by using `.read_html`. You can achieve the dataframe type of table you are looking for using that.

```
import pandas as pd

tables = pd.read_html(url)
df = pd.concat( [ table for table in tables ] )
```

**Output:**

```
print (df)
                          0             1
0            Previous Close          5.50
1                      Open          5.50
2                       Bid      5.47 x 0
3                       Ask      5.51 x 0
4               Day's Range   5.47 - 5.51
5             52 Week Range   3.58 - 6.49
6                    Volume        634191
7               Avg. Volume        675718
0                Market Cap      660.137M
1         Beta (3Y Monthly)          0.10
2            PE Ratio (TTM)         31.49
3                 EPS (TTM)          0.17
4             Earnings Date           NaN
5  Forward Dividend & Yield  0.15 (2.82%)
6          Ex-Dividend Date    2019-02-12
7             1y Target Est          5.17
```

Comment: thanks we are almost there. I modified the codes to put the data in a list             
df=[]
for ele in spans:
    data = ele.text
    df.append(data)
Howevery this gives me a long list : ['Previous Close',
 '5.52',
 'Open',
 '5.49',
 'Bid',
 'Ask',
 "Day's Range",
 '52 Week Range',
 'Volume',
 '1,164,604',
 'Avg. Volume',
 '660,530',
 'Market Cap',..]' How do achieve putting them in a dataframe like :                           
 Open 5.49
Volume 1,164,604

Comment: pretty easy to do. are you only interested in keeping Open and Volume?

Comment: no, all the keys and values. open and close are only examples

Comment: can you do me a favor, edit your original question to include that code that generated your list. You can just add it to the bottom. I just need a way to re-produce your output so I can see what I'm working with

Comment: @Candice, you provided the url which is enough for me to get it. I'll have this back to you within the hour.

Comment: @Candice. There is an easier way to grab that into a dataframe using pandas. I offer that solution above. I still included the  BeautifulSoup way.

Comment: Thanks! Didn’t know pandas is this powerful

Comment: you're welcome. usually when I need to do any scraping I'll just try pandas first and see what it spits out, as it only takes a few lines to do. If it can give me relatively what I want (maybe I need to work it around a little bit), I usually just go with that. If it doesn't return what I need in a nice way, or missing values, or the site is dynamic, then I start playing with beautifulsoup to start parsing. I just like the path of least resistance.