# attribute error when parsing html table with beautifulSoup4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am trying to get the rank, country name, population, density and the surface from a table using `BeautifulSoup4`. When I use `table.find_all('tr')`, it returns the following error:

> AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'find_all'

I guess the problem origin is the:

```
table = soup.find_all("table",attrs={"class":"wikitable sortable"})
```

That returns a list of one element, which contains the `tbody`, and I cannot loop over it!

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

r = requests.get("https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_des_pays_par_densit%C3%A9_de_population")

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
table = soup.find_all("table",attrs={"class":"wikitable sortable"})
for i in table.find_all('tr'):

    tds=i.find_all('td', string=True)
    tds_string = str(tds)
    specifications = str(re.sub("<.+?>"," ",tds_string))    
    print(specifications)
```

Below is the format of the table:

```
<table class="wikitable sortable" style="text-align:right">
<tbody><tr>
<th scope="col">Rang
</th>
<th scope="col">Pays <i>(ou territoire)</i>
</th>
<th scope="col">Densité (<abbr class="abbr" title="habitants">hab.</abbr>/km<sup>2</sup>)
</th>
<th scope="col">Population (<abbr class="abbr" title="habitants">hab.</abbr>)
</th>
<th scope="col">Superficie (km<sup>2</sup>)
</th></tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td align="left"><span class="datasortkey" data-sort-value="Monaco"><span class="flagicon"><a class="image" href="/wiki/Fichier:Flag_of_Monaco.svg" title="Drapeau de Monaco"><img alt="Drapeau de Monaco" class="noviewer thumbborder" data-file-height="600" data-file-width="750" decoding="async" height="16" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ea/Flag_of_Monaco.svg/20px-Flag_of_Monaco.svg.png" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ea/Flag_of_Monaco.svg/30px-Flag_of_Monaco.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ea/Flag_of_Monaco.svg/40px-Flag_of_Monaco.svg.png 2x" width="20"/></a> </span><a href="/wiki/Monaco" title="Monaco">Monaco</a></span></td>
<td>18 866</td>
<td>38 109</td>
<td>2,02
</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>2</td>
<td align="left"><span class="datasortkey" data-sort-value="Singapour"><span class="flagicon"><a class="image" href="/wiki/Fichier:Flag_of_Singapore.svg" title="Drapeau de Singapour"><img alt="Drapeau de Singapour" class="noviewer thumbborder" data-file-height="2880" data-file-width="4320" decoding="async" height="13" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/48/Flag_of_Singapore.svg/20px-Flag_of_Singapore.svg.png" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/48/Flag_of_Singapore.svg/30px-Flag_of_Singapore.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/48/Flag_of_Singapore.svg/40px-Flag_of_Singapore.svg.png 2x" width="20"/></a> </span><a href="/wiki/Singapour" title="Singapour">Singapour</a></span></td>
<td>7 829</td>
<td>5 423 148</td>
<td>692,7
</td></tr>
<tr>
.....
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Beautiful Soup: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'find\_all'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24108507/beautiful-soup-resultset-object-has-no-attribute-find-all)

Answer (score 0):

`find_all` returns a list. You probably want to use `find` which will return a table. Either that or iterate the list calling `find_all('tr')` on each table.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one table so use pandas

```
import pandas as pd
table = pd.read_html('https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_des_pays_par_densit%C3%A9_de_population')
# print(table)
table[0].to_csv(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\Data.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8-sig',index = False )
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. i could get the table, however it does not fit in the terminal, how can i fix that ?

Comment: write it to csv? See my edit and let me know. Change the filepath of course.

Comment: Did this answer your question?