# BeautifulSoup in Python Error using .find

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I know this may be a simple question but I really need help here.

I am trying to extract the total rebounds per game from this soup object.

I have tried to use the following code but got an error:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

url = "https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/a/abdulza01.html" 
request = urllib.request.Request(url) # create request object
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request) 
html = response.read().decode('unicode_escape') # convert to unicode format
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")    
table = soup.find('table', attrs={'id': 'per_game'})
results = table.find_all('tr')
for result in results[1:len(results)]:
    data = result.find_all('td')
data.find(attrs={'data-stat': 'trb_per_g'}).getText()  
data = [<td class="center iz" data-stat="age"></td>,
     <td class="left " data-stat="team_id"><a href="/teams/BOS/">BOS</a></td>,
     <td class="left " data-stat="lg_id">NBA</td>,
     <td class="center iz" data-stat="pos"></td>,
     <td class="right " data-stat="g">2</td>,
     <td class="right incomplete iz" data-stat="gs"></td>,
     <td class="right " data-stat="mp_per_g">12.0</td>,
     <td class="right " data-stat="fg_per_g">1.5</td>,
     <td class="right " data-stat="fga_per_g">6.5</td>,
     <td class="right " data-stat="fg_pct">.231</td>,
     <td class="right " data-stat="ft_per_g">1.0</td>,
     <td class="right " data-stat="fta_per_g">1.5</td>,
     <td class="right " data-stat="ft_pct">.667</td>,
     <td class="right " data-stat="orb_per_g">3.0</td>,
     <td class="right " data-stat="drb_per_g">4.5</td>,
     <td class="right " data-stat="trb_per_g">**7.5**</td>,
     <td class="right " data-stat="ast_per_g">1.5</td>,
     <td class="right " data-stat="stl_per_g">0.5</td>,
     <td class="right " data-stat="blk_per_g">0.5</td>,
     <td class="right " data-stat="tov_per_g">1.5</td>,
     <td class="right " data-stat="pf_per_g">2.0</td>,
     <td class="right " data-stat="pts_per_g">4.0</td>]
```

Error Message:
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

Is there something conceptually wrong with the code?

Comment: It's because the `data` object is not a `bs4.Tag` instance, so it does not have a `find()` method. Can you share the code that is producing the `data` object?

Comment: why not address @J.Taylor's request above ?

Comment: ok sure! Please see edited question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Beautiful Soup: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'find\_all'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24108507/beautiful-soup-resultset-object-has-no-attribute-find-all)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you search with `attribute` values you should also provide the `tag` name.
Try this below code.If only one element want to search try `find`.If more than one element want to search try `find_all` and then iterate the loop.Hope this helps.

```
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    html="""<html><td class="center iz" data-stat="age"></td>,
         <td class="left " data-stat="team_id"><a href="/teams/BOS/">BOS</a></td>,
         <td class="left " data-stat="lg_id">NBA</td>,
         <td class="center iz" data-stat="pos"></td>,
         <td class="right " data-stat="g">2</td>,
         <td class="right incomplete iz" data-stat="gs"></td>,
         <td class="right " data-stat="mp_per_g">12.0</td>,
         <td class="right " data-stat="fg_per_g">1.5</td>,
         <td class="right " data-stat="fga_per_g">6.5</td>,
         <td class="right " data-stat="fg_pct">.231</td>,
         <td class="right " data-stat="ft_per_g">1.0</td>,
         <td class="right " data-stat="fta_per_g">1.5</td>,
         <td class="right " data-stat="ft_pct">.667</td>,
         <td class="right " data-stat="orb_per_g">3.0</td>,
         <td class="right " data-stat="drb_per_g">4.5</td>,
         <td class="right " data-stat="trb_per_g">**7.5**</td>,
         <td class="right " data-stat="ast_per_g">1.5</td>,
         <td class="right " data-stat="stl_per_g">0.5</td>,
         <td class="right " data-stat="blk_per_g">0.5</td>,
         <td class="right " data-stat="tov_per_g">1.5</td>,
         <td class="right " data-stat="pf_per_g">2.0</td>,
         <td class="right " data-stat="pts_per_g">4.0</td></html>"""

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
    findtag=soup.find('td',attrs={"data-stat" : "trb_per_g" })
    print(findtag.text)
```

To search multiple items try this.

```
findtags=soup.find_all('td',attrs={"data-stat" : "trb_per_g" })
for tag in findtags:
  print(tag.text)
```

Comment: Hi Kajal, thanks but in this instance you have made it into a soup element tag object, which allows for the find method to be applied? My question has stated that it is a result set object, so I cant use find_all anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I think here is the answer of your question: [Beautiful Soup: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'find_all'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24108507/beautiful-soup-resultset-object-has-no-attribute-find-all)

The ResultSet object has no attribute 'find'. What you can do is access into each element and use 'find' to find what you want.

Comment: Hi there, do you have any idea what should be the correct syntax? So sorry!

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be faster to use a css selector combination to target by table id and attribute = value for the td cells of interest

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/a/abdulza01.html" 
soup = bs(requests.get(url).content, 'lxml')
data = [item.text for item in soup.select('#per_game [data-stat=trb_per_g]')]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.rename(columns=df.iloc[0], inplace = True)
df.drop(df.index[0], inplace = True)
print(df)
df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\Users\Desktop\Data.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8',index = False )
```