# Python Data Scraping - Extracting lines in the table where the tag '<td>' exists

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have been working on web scraping and have gotten pretty far in preparing my table from the web page I am scraping from.

The problem is that I can't get past getting the entries which only contain the data (lines which start with '< td >'). My code is as follows:

```
url = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demographics_of_Toronto_neighbourhoods')

soup = BeautifulSoup(url.text,'lxml')
print(soup.prettify())

table_classes = {'class':'sortable'}
raw_table = soup.findAll("table", table_classes)
print(raw_table)
```

*Putting the nest line of code causes the error **'ResultSet object has no attribute 'find_all'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()'**:*

```
td_tags = raw_table.find_all('<td>')
td_tags
```

*Looking at the data type I then tried to use find() and it still caused the same error, so I then tried looping over each line with the following code:*

```
for line in raw_table:
    if line.get_text().find('<td>') > -1:
        line
```

When I run this loop, nothing happens. if I put it outside of the 'if' loop then it just returns every line in the table 'Canada_table_raw'

How can I get the entries with the '' tag so that I can then put the results into a pandas data frame?

Comment: `find_all()` returns a list. So you need to access the list to perform beautiful soup operations -- either by index access `raw_table[0]` or  iterate over `raw_table` result, then perform `table.find_all('td')`

Comment: So I used the code `td_tags = raw_table[0].find_all('td')` and got a very large list which looks something like this: 

[<td><b>Toronto <a class="mw-redirect" href="/wiki/Census_metropolitan_area" title="Census metropolitan area">CMA</a> Average</b>
 </td>, <td>
 </td>, <td>All
  ...
</td>, <td>7.9
 </td>, <td>Italian (11.1%)
 </td>, <td>11.1% Italian
 </td>, ...]

Is this what the output should look like?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Beautiful Soup: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'find\_all'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24108507/beautiful-soup-resultset-object-has-no-attribute-find-all)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing one piece of code to get the parser to run.

```
url = requests.get(
    'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demographics_of_Toronto_neighbourhoods')

soup = BeautifulSoup(url.text, 'lxml')

table_classes = {'class': 'sortable'}
raw_table = soup.findAll("table", table_classes)
#print(raw_table)
for td in raw_table:
    print(td.findAll('td'))
```

As the error code says. You are returning a ResultSet Object. So you need to iterate over the object to get the specific elements that you need. In this case we are returning all of the td elements that are in the  ResultsSet with the following output:

```
[<td><b>Toronto <a class="mw-redirect" href="/wiki/Census_metropolitan_area" title="Census metropolitan area">CMA</a> Average</b>
</td>, <td>
</td>, <td>All
</td>, <td><b>5,113,149</b>
</td>, <td><b>5903.63</b>
</td>, <td><b>866</b>
</td>, <td><b>9.0</b>
</td>, <td><b>40,704</b>
</td>, <td><b>10.6</b>
</td>, <td><b>11.4</b>
</td>, <td>
</td>, <td>
</td>, <td>
</td>, <td><a href="/wiki
........
```

Now you just need to decide what elements you are looking for and edit the td to get the results you want.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response @Edeki, but when I run your code I get the following error message: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'findAll'. I tried to use 'find' instead and it was only returning the first instance. Do I need to use arrays somewhere?

Comment: Try it now I just copy and pasted exactly what I used. I think I mistyped a find when I meant to use FindAll. Let me know if it still doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks @Edeki! It works now. I just tweaked this by changing 'td' to 'tr' and now all the lines are separated in different blocks of code bound by 'tr'. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

Why not use select and grab all the td elements.

```
data = [item.text for item in soup.select('.sortable td')]
```