# Attribute Error with FindAll Function for Beautiful Soup

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to collect the stock tickers from https://finance.yahoo.com/u/yahoo-finance/watchlists/420_stocks/, and I keep getting a attribute error.

I have also tried findAll and find_All, both capital A and undercase.

```
def cannabisTickersList():   
    page = urllib.request.urlopen('https://finance.yahoo.com/u/yahoo-finance/watchlists/420_stocks/').read()
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
    table = soup.find_all('table', {"class" : 'cwl-symbols'})   
    cannabisTickers = []
    for table in table.find_all('tr'):
        cannabisTicker = table.find_all('td')
        cannabisTickers.append(cannabisTicker)
    with open("cannabisTickers.pickle", "wb") as f:
        pickle.dump(cannabisTickers, f)
    print([s.strip('\n') for s in cannabisTickers])
    return cannabisTickers
```

```
"ResultSet object has no attribute '%s'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?" % key
```

AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find_all'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

Comment: You are iterating over a sequence `table` but are using the same name for the `for...in...` loop. That cannot be good. Just to be clear, it is this part: `for table in table.find_all('tr'):`

Comment: Did you check the page source for the existence of the contents that you wish to seek?

Comment: even when I change "for table" to any other variable, I get the same error message. Also, the webpage has many tr and td tags under the table tag

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Beautiful Soup: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'find\_all'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24108507/beautiful-soup-resultset-object-has-no-attribute-find-all)