# Extracting Sub-tag text with BeautfulSoup Issue

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

I am having issue with some code that I am running. This is to extract, and ultimately create a list of names that are on a website. This is to capture the name in the following:

```
<th class="left " data-append-csv="David-Cornell" data-stat="player" scope="row"><a href="/en/players/0c9aad01/David-Cornell">David Cornell</a></th>
```

Now I've already created code to capture all of these instances, however even when I use find instances within the code to capture the next tag, I'm getting errors on this. I suspect there is a way for me to just parse the text received, but that would be rather a lot for the purposes, especially when there are a lot of differing pages.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bsoup
import requests as reqs

page = reqs.get("https://fbref.com/en/squads/986a26c1/Northampton-Town")
parsepage = bsoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

findplayers = parsepage.find_all('th',attrs={"data-stat":"player"}).find_next('a')
print(findplayers)
```

So I can't for the life of me capture the next tag - I've tried a series of iterations, and the error I get when running this, is the following:

> AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find_next'. You're
>   probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call
>   find_all() when you meant to call find()?

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Your link seems to be broken.

Comment: you can't use find_next on list with many elements, you have to use it with every element separatelly - use `for`-loop

Comment: Yeah the link was broken - just forgot to add the bit as code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Beautiful Soup: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'find\_all'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24108507/beautiful-soup-resultset-object-has-no-attribute-find-all)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find_all` gives list with many elements and you have to use `find_next` with every element separatelly. You have to use `for`-loop

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bsoup
import requests as reqs

page = reqs.get("https://fbref.com/en/squads/986a26c1/Northampton-Town")
parsepage = bsoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

finndplayers = parsepage.find_all('th',attrs={"data-stat":"player"})

for item in findplayers:
    print( item.find_next('a') )
```

Answer (score 0):

You could alter your selector and with `select` do the following

```
players = [item.text for item in parsepage.select('#stats_player tbody th')]
```

The names are all in `th` of table body (`tbody`) with id `stats_player`

Or alternatively

```
#stats_player th.left a
```

These are slightly faster than the alternatives which use attributes such as:

```
#stats_player [data-append-csv]
```