# Treating a list of items like a single item error: how to find links within each 'link' within string already scraped

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am writing a python code to scrape the pdfs of meetings off this website: https://www.gmcameetings.co.uk 
The pdf links are within links, which are also within links. I have the first set of links off the page above, then I need to scrape links within the new urls. 
When I do this I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find_all'. You're 
probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call 
find_all() when you meant to call find()?
```

This is my code so far which is all fine and checked in jupyter notebook:

```
# importing libaries and defining
import requests
import urllib.request
import time 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

# set url
url = "https://www.gmcameetings.co.uk/" 

# grab html 
r = requests.get(url)
page = r.text
soup = bs(page,'lxml')

# creating folder to store pfds - if not create seperate folder
folder_location = r'E:\Internship\WORK'

# getting all meeting href off url
meeting_links = soup.find_all('a',href='TRUE')
for link in meeting_links:
    print(link['href'])
    if link['href'].find('/meetings/')>1:
        print("Meeting!")
```

This is the line that then receives the error:

```
second_links = meeting_links.find_all('a', href='TRUE')
```

I have tried the find() as python suggests but that doesn't work either. But I understand that it can't treat meeting_links as a single item.

So basically, how do you search for links within each bit of the new string variable (meeting_links).

I already have code to get the pdfs once I have the second set of urls which seems to work fine but need to obviously get these first. 
Hopefully this makes sense and I've explained ok - I only properly started using python on Monday so I'm a complete beginner.

Comment: Change the string `'TRUE'` to boolean `True`: `second_links = meeting_links.find_all('a', href=True)` Running your script with this change works on me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Beautiful Soup: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'find\_all'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24108507/beautiful-soup-resultset-object-has-no-attribute-find-all)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all meeting links try

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

# set url
url = "https://www.gmcameetings.co.uk/" 

# grab html 
r = requests.get(url)
page = r.text
soup = bs(page,'lxml')

# Scrape to find all links
all_links = soup.find_all('a', href=True)

# Loop through links to find those containing '/meetings/'
meeting_links = []
for link in all_links:
    href = link['href']
    if '/meetings/' in href:
        meeting_links.append(href)
print(meeting_links)
```

The `.find()` function that you use in your original code is specific to beautiful soup objects. To find a substring within a string, just use native Python: `'a' in 'abcd'`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I've updated my response. You don't need the "`second_links`", you get them from `soup.find_all()` directly

Comment: I've run this and it seems to return all of the links on the original url I put at the top of the question (https://www.gmcameetings.co.uk). Does this mean the part #getting all meeting hrefs could be wrong?

Comment: Hey Rachel, my original comment was to point the bug in your code (using the string `'TRUE'` instead of the boolean `True`). I've updated my comment to show how to get all of the links that contain `'/meetings/'`