# how to return data from multiple pages from table in url using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i am trying to retrieve the code as well as title but somehow i am not able to retrieve the website is
 https://www.unspsc.org/search-code/default.aspx?CSS=51%&Type=desc&SS%27

here i have tried to get the value from the table

```
    import requests
    unspsc_link = "https://www.unspsc.org/search-code/default.aspx? 
     CSS=51%&Type=desc&SS%27"

     link = requests.get(unspsc_link).text

    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    soup = BeautifulSoup(link, 'lxml')

    print(soup.prettify())

    all_table = soup.find_all('table')
    print(all_table)

    right_table = soup.find_all('table', 
    id="dnn_ctr1535_UNSPSCSearch_gvDetailsSearchView")

    tables = right_table.find_all('td')
    print(tables)
```

the errors AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

i expect to save the code as well as title in a list and save it  in dataframe later

is there any way to continue to next page without manually providing values like in search code like 51%  as there as more than 20 pages inside  51%

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Beautiful Soup: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'find\_all'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24108507/beautiful-soup-resultset-object-has-no-attribute-find-all)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[From the documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#miscellaneous)

> AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'foo' - This
>   usually happens because you expected find_all() to return a single tag
>   or string. But find_all() returns a *list* of tags and strings–a
>   ResultSet object. You need to iterate over the list and look at the
>   .foo of each one. Or, if you really only want one result, **you need to
>   use find() instead of find_all()**

Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
unspsc_link = "https://www.unspsc.org/search-code/default.aspx?CSS=51%&Type=desc&SS%27"
link = requests.get(unspsc_link).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(link, 'lxml')
right_table = soup.find('table', id="dnn_ctr1535_UNSPSCSearch_gvDetailsSearchView")
df = pd.read_html(str(right_table))[0]
# Clean up the DataFrame
df = df[[0, 1]]
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
df = df[1:]
print(df)
```

Output:

```
0              Code                                              Title
1          51180000                   Hormones and hormone antagonists
2          51280000                                     Antibacterials
3          51290000                                    Antidepressants
4          51390000                Sympathomimetic or adrenergic drugs
5          51460000                                       Herbal drugs
...
```

Notes:

- The row order may be a little different but the data seems to be the same.
- You will have to remove the last one or two rows
  from the DataFrame as they are not relevant.
- This is the data from the first page only. Look into
  [selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/) to get the data from all pages by clicking on the buttons `[1] [2] ...`. You can also use `requests` to emulate the POST request but it is a bit difficult for this site (IMHO).

Comment: i just want to get code and title not anything else

Comment: how can i request for the next pages @Bitto Bennichan  as i cannot use selenium thanks for help

Comment: @ParthTiwari When you click on the `[1] [2]` etc a post request is being sent in the background. You can find this from your browser dev tools network tab.  I was not able to get that data from the site this way as it seemed very complicated as mentioned in my answer . See the documentation : https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests for how to send the request. Also consider asking a new question if you are unable to work it out - someone in the community with a little more experience in this might be able to help. Great Day!

Comment: actually it does not return the same result from the web page as the it returned 100  but on the first page it's not same matching

Comment: @ParthTiwari Pls go to the link and refresh the page. It is giving results in a different order every time you refresh the page! I am assuming  this is the data from any of the 20 pages. I believe it is not sorted any any order. So each time you send a request it is giving you randomly top 100 or so items from that list!