# Problem with printing in a single line extracted text from multiple links that are contained in divs with the same class

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract text from a page that has several divs with the same class. Each div contains different number of links with text. The extracted text from each div needs to be printed in a single line.

If for example one div contains three links and the other div contains 2 links, I want to extract the text from the three links in the first div and print the results in a single line and extract the text from the two links in the second div and print it in a new line. I also want to store the extracted data as a single item in an array.

The code below prints correctly the combined data however in addition to the extracted text, it also prints the `<a>` tags and the URLs. I tried to add the text attribute (`content.text`) however I got the following error:

> AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'text'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

```py
    from urllib.request import urlopen
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    html = urlopen("URL")
    bs = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), "html.parser")    
    int_array = []
    int_data = bs.findAll("div", {"class": "new_titles"})
    for div in int_data:
        content = div.find_all("a")
        int_array.append(content)
        print(content)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Beautiful Soup: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'find\_all'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24108507/beautiful-soup-resultset-object-has-no-attribute-find-all)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code.I think you are looking after this.

```
bs = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), "html.parser")
int_array = []
int_data = bs.findAll("div", {"class": "new_titles"})
for div in int_data:
    item=[a.text.strip() for a in div.find_all("a")]
    content =' '.join(item)    
    int_array.append(content)
    print(content)
```

Comment: Thank you Thomas and Kunduk  for your help. I tested both solutions on my URL. Kunduk's solution worked exactly as intended. Thomas solution did not work right away using my URL I will accept Kunduk's solution. Thank you both for taking the time tohelp me with this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The error message says it all: you are treating a list of hyperlinks (`div.find_all("a")` will give you many) like a single item, if you just put `.text` after it.

Similar to the `<div>` elements, you need to loop over the links and make use of the text of each individual link.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = urlopen("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57732994/problem-with-printing-in-a-single-line-extracted-text-from-multiple-links-that-a/57733094?noredirect=1#comment101906332_57733094")
bs = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), "html.parser")
int_data = bs.findAll("div")
for div in int_data:
    int_array = []
    content = div.find_all("a")
    for link in content:
        int_array.append(link.text.replace("\n", "").replace("\r", ""))
    print("***"+" ".join(int_array)+"***")
```

Comment: @Menachem: I've added a full example which works for this SO page