# How to pull multiple html tags from beautifulSoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to use beautifulSoup to extract several tags out of the html page. The page contains a list of rankings from 1-100, so I'd like to extract all of the  and  tags for each item.

I've tried using the following code:

```
info = soup.find_all('tbody')

for item in info.find_all('tr'):
    for cells in item.find_all('td'):
        print (cells)
```

but keep getting the same AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find_all'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

```
info = soup.find_all('tbody')
```

output: tbody

```
<tr

<td class="field-index ">1/td

<td class="field-release "><a class="link-release" href="/release/712">The Beatles [White Album]</a>/td

<td class="field-performer "><a class="link-performer" href="/artist/41">The Beatles</a></td

<td class="field-covers text-right">1633/td

</tr
```

For each `<tr>` tag of this page, I want to pull every `<td>` tag inside. So for the first I need to return:

```
1
The Beatles [White Album]
The Beatles
1633
```

Please let me know how to fix this.

Comment: can you provide the URL of the page you're trying to scrape?

Comment: Sure! thanks for responding so fast.  The link is: https://secondhandsongs.com/statistics?sort=covers&list=stats_release_covers

Comment: Add a `print(info)` to see what you get. You can't do `info.find_all(...` from a `list`. Follow the advice change "Did you call **find_all()** when you meant to call **find()**?"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Beautiful Soup: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'find\_all'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24108507/beautiful-soup-resultset-object-has-no-attribute-find-all)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just use pandas

```
import pandas as pd

table = pd.read_html('https://secondhandsongs.com/statistics?sort=covers&list=stats_release_covers')[0]
print(table)
```

Otherwise, you could grab the table by [id](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/ID_selectors) and add in `tr` [type selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Type_selectors) with [descendant combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator) so you have all rows; and then loop the rows grabbing the `tds`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

r = requests.get('https://secondhandsongs.com/statistics?sort=covers&list=stats_release_covers')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
rows = soup.select('#vw tr')
for row in rows:
    print([td.text for td in row.select('td')])
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Should've realize the url's page was already setup as a table  that I can extract from.