# How to remove tags with find_all in Beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I've been able to remove text from find, but when using `find_all` I'll get an error.

```py
equipmentType = category.find_all("div", {"class":"ExResult-details ExResult-equipmentType"}).text

print(equipmentType)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scrape.py", line 17, in <module>
    equipmentType = category.find_all("div", {"class":"ExResult-details ExResult-equipmentType"}).text
  File "/home/bert/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 1578, in __getattr__
    "ResultSet object has no attribute '%s'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?" % key
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'text'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?
```

Comment: As the error says it does not have attribute `text`.because it a resultSet. You could iterate over the list and get the `text` out of each element

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Beautiful Soup: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'find\_all'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24108507/beautiful-soup-resultset-object-has-no-attribute-find-all)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the last line of the Traceback:

`ResultSet object has no attribute 'text'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item.`

`find_all()` returns a set. What you want to do is iterate through the set, and get the text of each element:

```
equipment_list = category.find_all("div", {"class":"ExResult-details ExResult-equipmentType"})

for equipmentType in equipment_list:
    print(equipmentType.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

From the error message: `You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?`

That's saying that `find_all` returns a `ResultSet` and `ResultSet` has no attribute `text`.  Maybe try:

```
equipment_type = [item.text for item in category.find_all("div", {"class":"ExResult-details ExResult-equipmentType"})]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate through the Result set something like this:

```py
mydivs = [item.text.strip() for item in page_soup.find_all("div", {"id":"pil_name"})]
```

this is just an example from my code since I ran into the same problem