# Extract Text from div using bs4

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I've got stuck on a (probably really simple) problem.

I'm scraping a website using python, chrome web driver and selenium.

So I could find the div classes with the information, but i can't extract the text inside.

The following is the code I am using:

```
 html = driver.page_source
print(html)

soup = bs4(html, "lxml")

#find infos
div = soup.find_all('div', class_="order-line-prod-material ng-binding")
div
```

and then the output is:

```
[<div class="order-line-prod-material ng-binding">AQ4174-010</div>,
 <div class="order-line-prod-material ng-binding">AQ4176-010</div>,
 <div class="order-line-prod-material ng-binding">AT7899-010</div>,
 <div class="order-line-prod-material ng-binding">AT7900-010</div>,
 <div class="order-line-prod-material ng-binding">AT7975-010</div>,
 <div class="order-line-prod-material ng-binding">AT8120-010</div>,
 <div class="order-line-prod-material ng-binding">AT8153-010</div>]
```

when i tried to use:

```
div.text
```

The error message i get is the following:

ResultSet object has no attribute 'text'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

So i know i have to use a for loop but the examples I found online usually go something like this:

```
for a in div.find_all('a'):
    print(a.text)
```

The thing I don't understand is I don't have an a tag inside the div class, so over what do i have to iterate to get the text I want?

Really appreciate your help.

Have a great day

Comment: In python, indent matters... please fix the indent in your code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Beautiful Soup: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'find\_all'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24108507/beautiful-soup-resultset-object-has-no-attribute-find-all)

Answer (score 1):

if there are multiple values returned by find.all,then it should be treated as lists.
This should print the text from each div.

```
#find infos
divs = soup.find_all('div', class_="order-line-prod-material ng-binding")
for div in divs:
    print(div.text)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot: It definitely leads me on the right track... i still get an error message tough: SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing. So i looked it up and it seems its out of range, if its any help the variable divs is of type: element.ResultSet