# Is it possible to extract the text between the <p> tags in a html document?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am using BeautifulSoup to extract content from html files.
I have several thousand extracted html files and want to extract the content between the p tags in all files. 
Here is the relevant code:

```
for line in text:
    soup = bs(line, 'html.parser')
    autor = soup.find_all('p').text
    s = autor.replace('\\n', '')
    l.append(s)
```

I want to use find_all().text to extract the text between all p tags, but I am getting this error:

ResultSet object has no attribute 'text'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

If I am using just find().text

```
autor = soup.find('p').text
```

I just get the first p tag of every file.

Somebody can help?

Comment: I would assume you need to iterate through `soup.find('p')`, and for each item you get the `text` attribute.

Comment: You better post html example plus expected output

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Beautiful Soup: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'find\_all'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24108507/beautiful-soup-resultset-object-has-no-attribute-find-all)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text naturally separated by new lines:

```py
paragraph_text = '\n\n'.join(p.text for p in soup.find_all('p'))
```

Or, e.g., if you want to connect the paragraphs by spaces:

```py
paragraph_text = ' '.join(p.text for p in soup.find_all('p'))
```

A list of all the texts in `<p>`:

```py
paragraphs = [p.text for p in soup.find_all('p')]
```