# In BeautifulSoup / Python, how do I extract a single element from a result set?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, resultset

I'm using Python 3.7 and BeautifulSoup 4.  I'm having a problem getting text from an element.  I'm trying this

```
req = urllib2.Request(fullurl, headers=settings.HDR)
html = urllib2.urlopen(req, timeout=settings.SOCKET_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS).read()
bs = BeautifulSoup(html, features="lxml")
...
author_elts = bs.find_all("a", class_="author")
author_elt = author_elts.first
```

But on the "author_elt = author_elts.first" line, I'm getting the error

```
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'first'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()
```

What's the right way to extract the element from the ResultSet?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Beautiful Soup: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'find\_all'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24108507/beautiful-soup-resultset-object-has-no-attribute-find-all)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find_all` return a list, why did you not use `author_elts[0]` to get the first element ?