# Extract data in Python using beautifulsoup

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract data from https://ash.confex.com/ash/2019/webprogram/start.htm and getting an error with `find_all` of **beautifulsoup**

```
import webbrowser
import os
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys
import wget
import pandas as pd
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome('D:\\crome drive\\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://ash.confex.com/ash/2019/webprogram/start.html')
searchterm = driver.find_element_by_id("words").send_keys("CAR-T")
driver.find_element_by_name("submit").click()
#driver.find_element_by_tag_name("resulttitle")
#driver.find_element_by_class_name("a")

soup_level1=BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
#fl=soup_level1.find_all(class_='soup_level1')
results = soup_level1.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'resulttitle'})
tag = results.findall('a', attrs='href')
```

I am getting error

> AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'findall'. You're
>   probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call
>   find_all() when you meant to call find()?

Comment: The error description cannot get any simpler :). You need to iterate over the results and then call findall.

Comment: Once you are using find_all, then findall. Have you tried with findAll?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Beautiful Soup: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'find\_all'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24108507/beautiful-soup-resultset-object-has-no-attribute-find-all)

Answer (score 1):

Yeah it's exactly as the error says - the `find_all` method is supposed to be used on an html tree but in your code the variable `results` is a ResultSet object. In bs4 this is a list where each item is an HTML tree.

```
results = soup_level1.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'resulttitle'})
print(type(results))   # <class 'bs4.element.ResultSet'>
print(results)   # []
```

This also shows that your `results` is empty. I searched through the HTML of and didn't see any div with class = "resulttitle" so you may want to double check what you're looking for.

In theory, if your `results` variable weren't empty, you could loop through each item in `results` *and then* find all of the links you're looking for:

```
results = soup_level1.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'resulttitle'})
for result in results:
    tag_list = result.find_all('a', attrs='href)     
    # this will yield another list where each item is an HTML tree
```

Comment: Hi Joseph, In results below information are there and I want to extract <a href> from that eg. a href="Paper124312.html"