# Python Multi Page Web Scraping Text Only

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new to python. I am currently working on web scraping. The task is to scrape the first 5 pages of the Dell Community Inspiron questions. I have code that runs and returns the information I need. However, I am not able to get the text only. My current code returns the text + html. I have tried placing .text at various points of the code but only get errors when I do so.

The most common error being: "AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'text'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?"

Below is my code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os, csv
from time import sleep



pages = ['https://www.dell.com/community/Inspiron/bd-p/Inspiron',
        'https://www.dell.com/community/Inspiron/bd-p/Inspiron/page/2',
        'https://www.dell.com/community/Inspiron/bd-p/Inspiron/page/3',
        'https://www.dell.com/community/Inspiron/bd-p/Inspiron/page/4',
        'https://www.dell.com/community/Inspiron/bd-p/Inspiron/page/5'
    
    ]
import requests
data = []

for page in pages:
    r = requests.get(page)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    rows = soup.select('tbody tr')
    
    for row in rows:
        d = dict()
        d['title'] = soup.find_all ('a', attrs = {'class': 'page-link lia-link-navigation lia-custom-event'})
        d['author'] = soup.find_all ('span', attrs = {'class': 'login-bold'})
        d['time'] = soup.find_all ('span', attrs = {'class': 'local-time'})
        d['kudos'] = soup.find_all ('div', attrs = {'class': 'lia-component-messages-column-message-kudos-count'})
        d['messages'] = soup.find_all ('div', attrs = {'class': 'lia-component-messages-column-message-replies-count'})
        d['views'] = soup.find_all ('div', attrs = {'class': 'lia-component-messages-column-topic-views-count'})
        d['solved'] = soup.find_all ('td', attrs = {'aria-label': 'triangletop lia-data-cell-secondary lia-data-cell-icon'})
        d['latest']= soup.find_all ('span', attrs = {'cssclass': 'lia-info-area-item'})
        data.append(d)
    
    sleep(10)
print(data[0])
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Beautiful Soup: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'find\_all'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24108507/beautiful-soup-resultset-object-has-no-attribute-find-all)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find_all` returns a *list* of html elements. If you wish to print the text of each element, you need to loop through each of those lists that you created using `find_all` and then apply the `.text` method to each individual entry. For example:

```py
titles = soup.find_all ('a', attrs = {'class': 'page-link lia-link-navigation lia-custom-event'})
for title in titles:
    print(title.text())
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Joseph the `find_all` returns a list of html elements, loop through each element of those list and then apply the `.text` method to each item.

Below I've used List comprehension to loop and apply `.text` method. Using `strip()` to remove any trailing's like \t, \n etc...

**Finalized code:**

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os, csv
from time import sleep



pages = ['https://www.dell.com/community/Inspiron/bd-p/Inspiron',
        'https://www.dell.com/community/Inspiron/bd-p/Inspiron/page/2',
        'https://www.dell.com/community/Inspiron/bd-p/Inspiron/page/3',
        'https://www.dell.com/community/Inspiron/bd-p/Inspiron/page/4',
        'https://www.dell.com/community/Inspiron/bd-p/Inspiron/page/5'

    ]
import requests
data = []

for page in pages:
    r = requests.get(page)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    rows = soup.select('tbody tr')

    for row in rows:
        d = dict()
        d['title'] = [i.text.strip() for i in soup.find_all ('a', attrs = {'class': 'page-link lia-link-navigation lia-custom-event'})]
        d['author'] = [i.text.strip() for i in soup.find_all ('span', attrs = {'class': 'login-bold'})]
        d['time'] = [i.text.strip() for i in soup.find_all ('span', attrs = {'class': 'local-time'})]
        d['kudos'] = [i.text.strip() for i in soup.find_all ('div', attrs = {'class': 'lia-component-messages-column-message-kudos-count'})]
        d['messages'] = [i.text.strip() for i in soup.find_all ('div', attrs = {'class': 'lia-component-messages-column-message-replies-count'})]
        d['views'] = [i.text.strip() for i in soup.find_all ('div', attrs = {'class': 'lia-component-messages-column-topic-views-count'})]
        d['solved'] = [i.text.strip() for i in soup.find_all ('td', attrs = {'aria-label': 'triangletop lia-data-cell-secondary lia-data-cell-icon'})]
        d['latest']= [i.text.strip() for i in soup.find_all ('span', attrs = {'cssclass': 'lia-info-area-item'})]
        data.append(d)

    sleep(10)
print(data[0])
```

**EDIT:** Include this in your code to save dictionary as csv.

```
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
pd.head()     # confirm if the data is correct
pd.to_csv('name.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: how would i convert this to a csv?