# BeautifulSoup finding multiple Categories

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to **scrape** some Wiki-page , just for training
and I'm stuck,

I Want to print Title of the page, last modified date and categories
this is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd


response = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eurovision_Song_Contest') 
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser") 


head=soup.find(class_='firstHeading').get_text()
print('wikipedia entry: '+head)

foot=soup.find(id='footer-info-lastmod').get_text()
print(foot)

cate=soup.find_all(class_='mw-normal-catlinks')
x=soup.findAll("li",attrs={"title"})
print(x)
```

but it says:
ResultSet object has no attribute 'get_text'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

I need to print : list of CATEGORIES
for example on this page :
[image]

Comment: Always give full trace back please. Your script work fine, except x is an empty list

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Beautiful Soup: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'find\_all'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24108507/beautiful-soup-resultset-object-has-no-attribute-find-all)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix your probleme by finding the parent div:

**CODE**:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 import requests
 import pandas as pd


 response = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eurovision_Song_Contest') 
 soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser") 


 head=soup.find(class_='firstHeading').get_text()
 print('wikipedia entry: '+head)

 foot=soup.find(id='footer-info-lastmod').get_text()
 print(foot)

 cate=soup.find_all(class_='mw-normal-catlinks')
 catdiv = soup.find("div",{"id":"mw-normal-catlinks"})
 categories = catdiv.find("ul").find_all("li")
 for cat in categories:
     print(cat.text)
```

**RESULTS:**

```
wikipedia entry: Eurovision Song Contest
 This page was last edited on 6 December 2019, at 10:20 (UTC).
Eurovision Song Contest
1956 establishments in Europe
Eurovision events
Music television
Pop music festivals
Recurring events established in 1956
Song contests
```

Answer (score 1):

This script prints header, footer and list of categories:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

response = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eurovision_Song_Contest')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

head=soup.find(class_='firstHeading').get_text()
print('wikipedia entry: {}'.format(head))      # better use str.format()

foot=soup.find(id='footer-info-lastmod').get_text(strip=True)   # use strip=True to strip the text of whitespace characters
print(foot)

categories = [li.get_text() for li in soup.select('#mw-normal-catlinks li')]
print(categories)
```

Prints:

```
wikipedia entry: Eurovision Song Contest
This page was last edited on 6 December 2019, at 10:20(UTC).
['Eurovision Song Contest', '1956 establishments in Europe', 'Eurovision events', 'Music television', 'Pop music festivals', 'Recurring events established in 1956', 'Song contests']
```

Answer (score 1):

Even simpler:

```
normal=soup.find(class_="mw-normal-catlinks")
categories=normal.find_all("a", )
for category in categories:    
        print(category.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script prints 'head' and 'foot' perfectly, so I'll focus on printing list of categories.

Firstly, find_all() returns a list of tags and not a single tag, hence trying 'get_text()' on list of tags gives you an error.

```
cate=soup.find_all(class_='mw-normal-catlinks')
print(cate.get_text())

AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'get_text'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?
```

In your case, as find_all() returns only one tag, so you could either use 'find()' or extract the tag(div) from the returned list.

```
cate=soup.find_all(class_='mw-normal-catlinks')[0]
```

Your categories are under 'ul' tag which is a child of 'div' tag here (which you extracted using find_all()), so you could directly access them and store them into a list like this-

```
cate=soup.find_all(class_='mw-normal-catlinks')[0]

x=cate.ul.get_text("|")

categoryList = x.split("|")

print(categoryList)
```

**Output:**
['Eurovision Song Contest', '1956 establishments in Europe', 'Eurovision events', 'Music television', 'Pop music festivals', 'Recurring events established in 1956', 'Song contests']