# Getting error AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find_all'

Tags: beautifulsoup

Hi I am trying to find out all the links under pagination thing and the pagination part code already extracted. but when i was trying to capture all the list items I am getting the following error:

**AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find_all'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://scrapingclub.com/exercise/list_basic/"

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

pages = soup.find_all('ul', class_='pagination')
links = pages.find_all('a', class_='page-link')
print(links)
```

[image]

I did not understand by the term AttributeError: **ResultSet object has no attribute 'find_all'.** can anybody check this what I am missing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Beautiful Soup: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'find\_all'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24108507/beautiful-soup-resultset-object-has-no-attribute-find-all)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you cannot call `.find_all()` or `.find()` on ResultSet returned by first `.find_all()` call.

This example will print all links from `pagination`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://scrapingclub.com/exercise/list_basic/"

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

pages = soup.find('ul', class_='pagination')          # <-- .find() to return only one element

for link in pages.find_all('a', class_='page-link'):  # <-- find_all() to return list of elements
    print(link)
```

Prints:

```
<a class="page-link" href="?page=2">2</a>
<a class="page-link" href="?page=3">3</a>
<a class="page-link" href="?page=4">4</a>
<a class="page-link" href="?page=5">5</a>
<a class="page-link" href="?page=6">6</a>
<a class="page-link" href="?page=7">7</a>
<a class="page-link" href="?page=2">Next</a>
```