# Web Scraping :- "" TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable "". How to fix this issue?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, typeerror

I have tried to fix this error but I can't.

I am trying to scrape a website and here is how it looks:

the variable str1 contain the web address of the website in the form of string.

```py
my_url = str1
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

data = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class": "_2kHMtA"})
```

And at last I tried to print this statement:

```py
y = data[2].div.img['alt']
print(y)
```

When I print this statement it always tries to show that error !
Please Help.

Answer (score 3):

Print your `data` object.  You haven't managed to find the data you're looking for, so you are trying to print the 3rd entry in nothing (hence the failure).

Without knowing your input html I can't say why that is.

AFAIK you can't pass a dict to `findAll`.  Rather you use keyword arguments, like so:

```py
soup.find_all("div", class="_myclass")
```

Note that `findAll` is an alias for `find_all`.

Note also that you can only run `find_all` on a *soup* object.  You *can't* run it on the results of a previous `find_all` object, which is a `ResultsSet` object (basically a list of soup objects).  (Although, of course, you can iterate over those soup objects if you needed to.)

Comment: Ah, the error is even further up.

Comment: this normally means that you are not calling it on the *soup* object at all: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59911101/getting-error-attributeerror-resultset-object-has-no-attribute-find-all.  Try running your code from scratch (with keyword args for good measure, and changing `findAll` to `find_all` for style)

Comment: May I share the prettify HTML when I runed the following :-
print(soup.prettify(data[1]))

Comment: This doesn't make sense: if you can `print(soup.prettify(data[1]))` then a fortiori you can `print(data)`.  Try running your code from the beginning again, only as written here/above.

Comment: if i use another url then it works fine

Comment: Now i was able to get the desired output when I runed the following:
```python
y = data[1].find("img", {"class":"_396cs4 _3exPp9"})
print(y["alt"])
#print(y)
```

Comment: good.  you can't call `find_all` on the results of a find, that's all. :)