# Scraping Table using BeautifulSoup and Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

im trying to scrape the first major table from the following site using BeautifulSoup :
https://dailyfantasyrankings.com.au/resources/nba/cheatsheet/moneyball/allproj.php

Im receiving the error:
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find_all'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

Im sure other parts of my code arent quite right but was hoping someone could assist!

Code:

```
import requests
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

URL = 'https://dailyfantasyrankings.com.au/resources/nba/cheatsheet/moneyball/allproj.php'
response = requests.get(URL)
html = response.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

table = soup.find('table', attrs={'class': 'xl12520945'})

columns = ['#', 'PLAYER', 'POS', '@', 'TEAM', 'OPP', 'M-UP', 'PACE', 'REST', 'PRICE', 'PROJ', 'VALUE', 'AVE']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)

trs = table.find_all('tr')
for tr in trs:
    tds = tr.find_all('td')
    row = [td.text.replace('\n','') for td in tds]
    df = df.append(pd.Series(row, index=columns), ignore_index=True)

df.to_csv('dfr_proj.csv', index = False)
```

Comment: This is an interesting problem because: 1. The data table is in an iframe so it's better to scrape the source of that iframe which is https://dailyfantasyrankings.com.au/resources/nba/htm/projections/mballproj.htm 2. Scraping the source of the table doesn't return the full source code html of the page. Once this is overcome you can easily scrape the table. I'm trying to solve it now and I'm excited to see how others solve it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Beautiful Soup: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'find\_all'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24108507/beautiful-soup-resultset-object-has-no-attribute-find-all)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table you're trying to scrape is in an iframe, so it's better to get the iframe source html instead of the page html

```
URL = 'https://dailyfantasyrankings.com.au/resources/nba/htm/projections/mballproj.htm'
```

Get the table with CSS selector instead of class name because there is an issue with how HTML is formatted on the source page:

```
table = soup.select("#Finish_20945 > table")[0]
```

Working code. Change are marked with code comments:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
#CHANGED LINE BELOW
URL = 'https://dailyfantasyrankings.com.au/resources/nba/htm/projections/mballproj.htm'
response = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
#CHANGED LINE BELOW
table = soup.select("#Finish_20945 > table")[0]
columns = ['#', 'PLAYER', 'POS', '@', 'TEAM', 'OPP', 'M-UP', 'PACE', 'REST', 'PRICE', 'PROJ', 'VALUE', 'AVE']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)
trs = table.find_all('tr')
for tr in trs:
    tds = tr.find_all('td')
    row = [td.text.replace('\n', '') for td in tds]
    print(row)
    # df = df.append(pd.Series(row, index=columns), ignore_index=True)

df.to_csv('dfr_proj.csv', index=False)
```

Output:

```
['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '↓', '↓', '', '\xa0', '\xa0', '\xa0', '\xa0', '\xa0']
['#', 'Player', '\xa0', 'Pos', '@', 'Team', 'Opp', 'M-UP', 'Pace', 'Rest', 'Price', 'Proj', 'Value', 'Ave', 'Last 5 Games']
['1', 'A. Davis', '\xa0', 'PF', 'A', 'LAL', 'NOP', '18', '3.5', 'B2B', '$10,800', '61', '5.6', '51', '70', '52', '61', '41', '37']
['2', 'B. Beal', '\xa0', 'SG', 'A', 'WAS', 'GSW', '5', '0.3', '1', '$9,600', '57', '5.9', '46', '34', '67', '53', '51', '67']
['3', 'L. James', '\xa0', 'SF', 'A', 'LAL', 'NOP', '3', '3.5', 'B2B', '$10,400', '53', '5.1', '51', '51', '50', '55', '\xa0', '45']
['4', 'N. Jokic', '\xa0', 'C', 'H', 'DEN', 'TOR', '19', '0.4', '1', '$10,100', '47', '4.7', '45', '53', '52', '50', '35', '35']
['5', 'P. Siakam', '\xa0', 'SF', 'A', 'TOR', 'DEN', '26', '-3.0', '1', '$8,400', '45', '5.4', '41', '34', '63', '28', '33', '50']
['6', 'K. Lowry', '\xa0', 'PG', 'A', 'TOR', 'DEN', '11', '-3.0', '1', '$7,600', '44', '5.8', '38', '43', '31', '57', '23', '47']
['7', 'A. Wiggins', '\xa0', 'SF', 'H', 'GSW', 'WAS', '11', '3.0', 'B2B', '$7,700', '42', '5.5', '36', '34', '34', '16', '\xa0', '46']
['8', 'B. Ingram', '\xa0', 'SF', 'H', 'NOP', 'LAL', '16', '0.5', '1', '$7,900', '40', '5.1', '40', '\xa0', '26', '32', '47', '47']
['9', 'C. Wood', 'GTD', 'PF', 'A', 'DET', 'SAC', '26', '-2.0', '1', '$7,900', '39', '4.9', '23', '48', '35', '44', '36', '48']
['10', 'D. Fox', 'GTD', 'PG', 'H', 'SAC', 'DET', '3', '-2.4', '1', '$7,500', '38', '5.1', '37', '34', '35', '36', '\xa0', '42']
['11', 'J. Holiday', '\xa0', 'SG', 'H', 'NOP', 'LAL', '24', '0.5', '1', '$8,900', '38', '4.3', '40', '35', '44', '52', '33', '40']
['12', 'D. Rose', '\xa0', 'PG', 'A', 'DET', 'SAC', '18', '-2.0', '1', '$6,000', '36', '6.0', '30', '11', '19', '17', '32', '47']
['13', 'Z. Williamson', '\xa0', 'PF', 'H', 'NOP', 'LAL', '16', '0.5', '1', '$8,300', '36', '4.3', '33', '41', '37', '41', '41', '33']
['14', 'D. Lee', '\xa0', 'SG', 'H', 'GSW', 'WAS', '7', '3.0', 'B2B', '$6,100', '34', '5.7', '24', '26', '36', '32', '25', '41']
['15', 'M. Chriss', '\xa0', 'C', 'H', 'GSW', 'WAS', '21', '3.0', 'B2B', '$6,400', '34', '5.3', '22', '21', '\xa0', '37', '20', '36']
['16', 'O. Anunoby', '\xa0', 'SF', 'A', 'TOR', 'DEN', '27', '-3.0', '1', '$5,000', '33', '6.7', '24', '12', '31', '19', '29', '49']
['17', 'J. Murray', '\xa0', 'PG', 'H', 'DEN', 'TOR', '15', '0.4', '1', '$7,200', '32', '4.4', '33', '49', '35', '29', '39', '17']
['18', 'L. Ball', '\xa0', 'PG', 'H', 'NOP', 'LAL', '30', '0.5', '1', '$6,900', '32', '4.6', '32', '33', '32', '33', '30', '46']
['19', 'E. Paschall', '\xa0', 'PF', 'H', 'GSW', 'WAS', '21', '3.0', 'B2B', '$4,600', '30', '6.5', '23', '21', '20', '20', '30', '34']
['20', 'N. Powell', '\xa0', 'SG', 'A', 'TOR', 'DEN', '10', '-3.0', '1', '$4,500', '28', '6.2', '26', '\xa0', '\xa0', '\xa0', '\xa0', '27']
['21', 'R. Hachimura', '\xa0', 'PF', 'A', 'WAS', 'GSW', '15', '0.3', '1', '$5,100', '28', '5.4', '25', '36', '25', '22', '20', '31']
['22', 'B. Hield', '\xa0', 'SG', 'H', 'SAC', 'DET', '26', '-2.4', '1', '$6,000', '27', '4.4', '32', '39', '12', '32', '24', '24']
['23', 'W. Barton', '\xa0', 'SF', 'H', 'DEN', 'TOR', '11', '0.4', '1', '$5,800', '26', '4.5', '31', '\xa0', '35', '25', '16', '25']
['24', 'H. Giles III', '\xa0', 'PF', 'H', 'SAC', 'DET', '7', '-2.4', '1', '$5,100', '26', '5.1', '15', '15', '33', '33', '29', '30']
['25', 'N. Bjelica', '\xa0', 'PF', 'H', 'SAC', 'DET', '11', '-2.4', '1', '$5,100', '26', '5.1', '27', '26', '24', '10', '31', '31']
['26', 'J. Grant', '\xa0', 'PF', 'H', 'DEN', 'TOR', '23', '0.4', '1', '$4,500', '25', '5.5', '21', '26', '8', '17', '35', '35']
['27', 'S. Napier', '\xa0', 'PG', 'A', 'WAS', 'GSW', '6', '0.3', '1', '$5,000', '24', '4.7', '22', '18', '17', '46', '22', '13']
['28', 'D. Bender', '\xa0', 'PF', 'H', 'GSW', 'WAS', '21', '3.0', 'B2B', '$3,900', '23', '5.9', '12', '\xa0', '20', '8', '13', '39']
['29', 'D. Favors', '\xa0', 'C', 'H', 'NOP', 'LAL', '30', '0.5', '1', '$5,400', '23', '4.3', '27', '21', '27', '24', '18', '37']
['30', 'K. Bazemore', '\xa0', 'SF', 'H', 'SAC', 'DET', '26', '-2.4', '1', '$5,400', '23', '4.2', '19', '25', '47', '28', '18', '26']
['31', 'D. Bertans', '\xa0', 'PF', 'A', 'WAS', 'GSW', '24', '0.3', '1', '$5,100', '23', '4.5', '26', '26', '25', '\xa0', '23', '19']
['32', 'H. Barnes', '\xa0', 'SF', 'H', 'SAC', 'DET', '29', '-2.4', '1', '$5,200', '23', '4.4', '25', '35', '36', '24', '29', '15']
['33', 'T. Bryant', '\xa0', 'C', 'A', 'WAS', 'GSW', '11', '0.3', '1', '$4,100', '23', '5.5', '25', '20', '13', '\xa0', '15', '22']
['34', 'B. Knight', '\xa0', 'PG', 'A', 'DET', 'SAC', '23', '-2.0', '1', '$3,900', '22', '5.8', '11', '\xa0', '1', '22', '25', '28']
['35', 'R.\r  Hollis-Jefferson', '\xa0', 'PF', 'A', 'TOR', 'DEN', '26', '-3.0', '1', '$4,000', '22', '5.4', '19', '12', '22', '18', '25', '15']
['36', 'I. Smith', '\xa0', 'PG', 'A', 'WAS', 'GSW', '8', '0.3', '1', '$5,000', '22', '4.3', '24', '26', '29', '30', '12', '16']
['37', 'R. Rondo', '\xa0', 'PG', 'A', 'LAL', 'NOP', '4', '3.5', 'B2B', '$4,300', '21', '4.9', '19', '14', '28', '7', '30', '10']
['38', 'A. Len', '\xa0', 'C', 'H', 'SAC', 'DET', '7', '-2.4', '1', '$4,000', '21', '5.2', '20', '\xa0', '16', '11', '26', '24']
['39', 'B. Bogdanovic', '\xa0', 'SG', 'H', 'SAC', 'DET', '25', '-2.4', '1', '$5,100', '20', '4.0', '24', '16', '32', '28', '23', '24']
['40', 'D. Howard', '\xa0', 'C', 'A', 'LAL', 'NOP', '29', '3.5', 'B2B', '$4,400', '20', '4.6', '22', '12', '20', '15', '36', '20']
['41', 'M. Mulder', '\xa0', '-', 'H', 'GSW', 'WAS', '7', '3.0', 'B2B', '-', '20', '-', '-', '\xa0', '\xa0', '\xa0', '7', '21']
['42', 'M. Morris', '\xa0', 'PG', 'H', 'DEN', 'TOR', '15', '0.4', '1', '$4,600', '19', '4.2', '19', '26', '12', '34', '29', '18']
['43', 'J. Henson', '\xa0', 'C', 'A', 'DET', 'SAC', '21', '-2.0', '1', '$4,500', '19', '4.3', '17', '4', '12', '31', '14', '21']
['44', 'N. Melli', '\xa0', 'PF', 'H', 'NOP', 'LAL', '30', '0.5', '1', '$4,100', '19', '4.7', '14', '17', '24', '30', '22', '20']
['45', 'K. Caldwell-Pope', '\xa0', 'SG', 'A', 'LAL', 'NOP', '2', '3.5', 'B2B', '$4,200', '19', '4.5', '17', '19', '16', '22', '20', '16']
['46', 'T. Brown Jr.', '\xa0', 'SF', 'A', 'WAS', 'GSW', '24', '0.3', '1', '$4,400', '19', '4.3', '23', '24', '17', '9', '12', '24']
['47', 'K. Looney', '\xa0', 'C', 'H', 'GSW', 'WAS', '15', '3.0', 'B2B', '$3,500', '19', '5.3', '10', '12', '15', '14', '16', '22']
['48', 'S. Mykhailiuk', '\xa0', 'SG', 'A', 'DET', 'SAC', '23', '-2.0', '1', '$3,500', '18', '5.2', '15', '13', '16', '8', '10', '27']
['49', 'L. Galloway', '\xa0', 'SG', 'A', 'DET', 'SAC', '18', '-2.0', '1', '$4,100', '18', '4.4', '17', '17', '13', '26', '14', '12']
['50', 'J. Toscano-Anderson', '\xa0', 'SF', 'H', 'GSW', 'WAS', '11', '3.0', 'B2B', '$4,300', '18', '4.2', '18', '32', '38', '13', '10', '15']
['51', 'A. Bradley', '\xa0', 'SG', 'A', 'LAL', 'NOP', '3', '3.5', 'B2B', '$4,000', '18', '4.4', '15', '33', '10', '8', '19', '8']
['52', 'P. Millsap', 'GTD', 'PF', 'H', 'DEN', 'TOR', '23', '0.4', '1', '$5,400', '17', '3.2', '25', '27', '11', '41', '17', '8']
['53', 'C. Boucher', '\xa0', 'PF', 'A', 'TOR', 'DEN', '25', '-3.0', '1', '$4,200', '17', '3.9', '16', '4', '21', '37', '20', '8']
['54', 'T. Snell', '\xa0', 'SG', 'A', 'DET', 'SAC', '23', '-2.0', '1', '$3,900', '17', '4.2', '15', '30', '15', '9', '28', '13']
['55', 'K. Kuzma', '\xa0', 'PF', 'A', 'LAL', 'NOP', '18', '3.5', 'B2B', '$4,400', '17', '3.8', '20', '17', '22', '13', '25', '16']
['56', 'A. Caruso', '\xa0', 'PG', 'A', 'LAL', 'NOP', '4', '3.5', 'B2B', '$4,000', '16', '4.1', '14', '18', '9', '32', '14', '14']
['57', 'M. Plumlee', '\xa0', 'C', 'H', 'DEN', 'TOR', '19', '0.4', '1', '$4,200', '16', '3.8', '19', '\xa0', '12', '17', '21', '16']
['58', 'T. Davis', '\xa0', 'SG', 'A', 'TOR', 'DEN', '10', '-3.0', '1', '$4,600', '16', '3.4', '16', '3', '19', '21', '20', '8']
['59', 'J. Hart', '\xa0', 'SG', 'H', 'NOP', 'LAL', '22', '0.5', '1', '$4,900', '15', '3.2', '24', '20', '33', '20', '17', '13']
['60', 'J. Robinson', '\xa0', 'PG', 'A', 'WAS', 'GSW', '19', '0.3', '1', '$3,900', '14', '3.6', '8', '14', '10', '10', '22', '18']
['61', 'G. Harris', '\xa0', 'SG', 'H', 'DEN', 'TOR', '21', '0.4', '1', '$4,300', '14', '3.3', '20', '18', '10', '24', '19', '10']
['62', 'C. Joseph', 'GTD', 'PG', 'H', 'SAC', 'DET', '3', '-2.4', '1', '$3,900', '14', '3.6', '17', '17', '5', '19', '33', '14']
['63', 'S. Doumbouya', '\xa0', 'PF', 'A', 'DET', 'SAC', '23', '-2.0', '1', '$3,500', '14', '4.0', '12', '10', '18', '14', '3', '14']
['64', 'M. Porter Jr.', '\xa0', 'PF', 'H', 'DEN', 'TOR', '23', '0.4', '1', '$3,900', '13', '3.4', '16', '\xa0', '5', '6', '22', '15']
['65', 'J. McGee', '\xa0', 'C', 'A', 'LAL', 'NOP', '29', '3.5', 'B2B', '$3,900', '12', '3.0', '20', '10', '14', '13', '21', '7']
['66', 'T. Maker', 'GTD', 'C', 'A', 'DET', 'SAC', '21', '-2.0', '1', '$4,600', '11', '2.5', '11', '25', '25', '16', '9', '6']
['67', 'I. Mahinmi', '\xa0', 'C', 'A', 'WAS', 'GSW', '11', '0.3', '1', '$4,100', '11', '2.6', '20', '18', '6', '21', '15', '14']
['68', 'M. Morris', '\xa0', 'SF', 'A', 'LAL', 'NOP', '18', '3.5', 'B2B', '$4,200', '10', '2.4', '19', '\xa0', '\xa0', '8', '13', '13']
['69', 'E. Moore', '\xa0', 'SF', 'H', 'NOP', 'LAL', '24', '0.5', '1', '$3,500', '9', '2.7', '16', '15', '10', '6', '3', '19']
['70', 'I. Bonga', '\xa0', 'SF', 'A', 'WAS', 'GSW', '19', '0.3', '1', '$3,500', '9', '2.7', '12', '8', '3', '13', '14', '7']
['71', 'T. Craig', '\xa0', 'SG', 'H', 'DEN', 'TOR', '21', '0.4', '1', '$3,900', '9', '2.3', '12', '20', '7', '6', '\xa0', '12']
['72', 'M. Wagner', '\xa0', 'C', 'A', 'WAS', 'GSW', '11', '0.3', '1', '$4,000', '8', '2.1', '20', '11', '12', '28', '8', '4']
['73', 'P. McCaw', '\xa0', 'SG', 'A', 'TOR', 'DEN', '10', '-3.0', '1', '$3,500', '8', '2.3', '13', '9', '\xa0', '\xa0', '\xa0', '7']
['74', 'M. Thomas', '\xa0', 'SG', 'A', 'TOR', 'DEN', '10', '-3.0', '1', '$3,500', '7', '2.0', '8', '1', '1', '18', '14', '4']
['75', 'J. Hayes', '\xa0', 'C', 'H', 'NOP', 'LAL', '30', '0.5', '1', '$3,500', '3', '0.9', '17', '11', '9', '0', '\xa0', '10']
['76', 'P. Dozier', '\xa0', 'SG', 'H', 'DEN', 'TOR', '15', '0.4', '1', '$3,500', '3', '0.7', '10', '6', '\xa0', '0', '3', '6']
['77', 'J. McRae', '\xa0', 'SG', 'H', 'DEN', 'TOR', '11', '0.4', '1', '$4,100', '2', '0.6', '20', '6', '\xa0', '0', '\xa0', '3']
['78', 'J. Okafor', '\xa0', 'C', 'H', 'NOP', 'LAL', '30', '0.5', '1', '$3,500', '2', '0.6', '16', '\xa0', '\xa0', '\xa0', '2', '\xa0']
['79', 'F. Jackson', '\xa0', 'PG', 'H', 'NOP', 'LAL', '30', '0.5', '1', '$3,500', '1', '0.2', '9', '7', '0', '\xa0', '\xa0', '4']
```

Comment: Thanks Thaer! however when i run the above code my output is empty. Am i missing something?

Comment: You mean the output to the CSV file or the output to the terminal? I worked only on the scraping part of the code.  I disabled importing into Panadas     # df = df.append(pd.Series(row, index=columns), ignore_index=True) so I can work on the scraping.

Comment: Hi Thaer, can i ask how did you get the iframe source html instead of the page html?

Comment: @RaymondHuynh It's in the page source. If you inspect the table and go a few levels up, you'll find <iframe name="i-frame2" class="
 hid fil" src="../../htm/projections/mballproj.htm" scrolling="no">
 <a href="../../htm/projections/mballproj.htm">../../htm/projections/mballproj.htm</a></iframe>. The src attribute of the iframe includes the URL to the source page of the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your answer: [Beautiful Soup: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'find_all'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24108507/beautiful-soup-resultset-object-has-no-attribute-find-all)

However, I tried running your script and was running into a different issue. The "table" element didn't even exist.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is just use Pandas to read in the table (it uses Beautifulsoup under the hood)

```
import pandas as pd

URL = 'https://dailyfantasyrankings.com.au/resources/nba/htm/projections/mballproj.htm'
df = pd.read_html(URL)[0]
df.columns = df.iloc[1,:]
df = df.iloc[2:,:]

df.to_csv('dfr_proj.csv', index=False)
```

**Output:**

```
print(df.to_string())
1      #              Player  NaN Pos  @ Team  Opp M-UP  Pace Rest    Price Proj Value Ave Last 5 Games Last 5 Games Last 5 Games Last 5 Games Last 5 Games
2      1            A. Davis  GTD  PF  A  LAL  NOP   18   3.5  B2B  $10,800   59   5.5  51           70           52           61           41           37
3      2             B. Beal  NaN  SG  A  WAS  GSW    5   0.3    1   $9,600   57   5.9  46           34           67           53           51           67
4      3            L. James  NaN  SF  A  LAL  NOP    3   3.5  B2B  $10,400   53   5.1  51           51           50           55          NaN           45
5      4            N. Jokic  NaN   C  H  DEN  TOR   19   0.4    1  $10,100   51   5.1  45           53           52           50           35           35
6      5           P. Siakam  NaN  SF  A  TOR  DEN   26  -3.0    1   $8,400   45   5.4  41           34           63           28           33           50
7      6            K. Lowry  NaN  PG  A  TOR  DEN   11  -3.0    1   $7,600   45   5.9  38           43           31           57           23           47
8      7          A. Wiggins  NaN  SF  H  GSW  WAS   11   3.0  B2B   $7,700   42   5.5  36           34           34           16          NaN           46
9      8             C. Wood  NaN  PF  A  DET  SAC   26  -2.0    1   $7,900   42   5.3  23           48           35           44           36           48
10     9           B. Ingram  NaN  SF  H  NOP  LAL   16   0.5    1   $7,900   40   5.1  40          NaN           26           32           47           47
11    10              D. Fox  NaN  PG  H  SAC  DET    3  -2.4    1   $7,500   38   5.1  37           34           35           36          NaN           42
12    11          J. Holiday  NaN  SG  H  NOP  LAL   24   0.5    1   $8,900   38   4.3  40           35           44           52           33           40
13    12             D. Rose  NaN  PG  A  DET  SAC   18  -2.0    1   $6,000   36   6.0  30           11           19           17           32           47
14    13       Z. Williamson  NaN  PF  H  NOP  LAL   16   0.5    1   $8,300   36   4.3  33           41           37           41           41           33
15    14           M. Chriss  NaN   C  H  GSW  WAS   21   3.0  B2B   $6,400   34   5.3  22           21          NaN           37           20           36
16    15          O. Anunoby  NaN  SF  A  TOR  DEN   27  -3.0    1   $5,000   33   6.7  24           12           31           19           29           49
17    16              D. Lee  NaN  SG  H  GSW  WAS    7   3.0  B2B   $6,100   32   5.3  24           26           36           32           25           41
18    17           J. Murray  NaN  PG  H  DEN  TOR   15   0.4    1   $7,200   32   4.4  33           49           35           29           39           17
19    18             L. Ball  NaN  PG  H  NOP  LAL   30   0.5    1   $6,900   32   4.6  32           33           32           33           30           46
20    19           N. Powell  NaN  SG  A  TOR  DEN   10  -3.0    1   $4,500   30   6.7  26          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN           27
21    20         E. Paschall  NaN  PF  H  GSW  WAS   21   3.0  B2B   $4,600   30   6.5  23           21           20           20           30           34
22    21            J. Grant  NaN  PF  H  DEN  TOR   23   0.4    1   $4,500   30   6.6  21           26            8           17           35           35
23    22        R. Hachimura  NaN  PF  A  WAS  GSW   15   0.3    1   $5,100   28   5.4  25           36           25           22           20           31
24    23            B. Hield  NaN  SG  H  SAC  DET   26  -2.4    1   $6,000   27   4.4  32           39           12           32           24           24
25    24           W. Barton  NaN  SF  H  DEN  TOR   11   0.4    1   $5,800   26   4.5  31          NaN           35           25           16           25
26    25        H. Giles III  NaN  PF  H  SAC  DET    7  -2.4    1   $5,100   26   5.1  15           15           33           33           29           30
27    26          N. Bjelica  NaN  PF  H  SAC  DET   11  -2.4    1   $5,100   26   5.1  27           26           24           10           31           31
28    27           S. Napier  NaN  PG  A  WAS  GSW    6   0.3    1   $5,000   24   4.7  22           18           17           46           22           13
29    28       M. Porter Jr.  NaN  PF  H  DEN  TOR   23   0.4    1   $3,900   23   6.0  16          NaN            5            6           22           15
30    29           D. Bender  NaN  PF  H  GSW  WAS   21   3.0  B2B   $3,900   23   5.9  12          NaN           20            8           13           39
31    30           D. Favors  NaN   C  H  NOP  LAL   30   0.5    1   $5,400   23   4.3  27           21           27           24           18           37
32    31         K. Bazemore  NaN  SF  H  SAC  DET   26  -2.4    1   $5,400   23   4.2  19           25           47           28           18           26
33    32          D. Bertans  NaN  PF  A  WAS  GSW   24   0.3    1   $5,100   23   4.5  26           26           25          NaN           23           19
34    33           H. Barnes  NaN  SF  H  SAC  DET   29  -2.4    1   $5,200   23   4.4  25           35           36           24           29           15
35    34           T. Bryant  NaN   C  A  WAS  GSW   11   0.3    1   $4,100   23   5.5  25           20           13          NaN           15           22
36    35           B. Knight  NaN  PG  A  DET  SAC   23  -2.0    1   $3,900   22   5.8  11          NaN            1           22           25           28
37    36           J. Henson  NaN   C  A  DET  SAC   21  -2.0    1   $4,500   22   5.0  17            4           12           31           14           21
38    37  R.  Hollis-Jeffers  NaN  PF  A  TOR  DEN   26  -3.0    1   $4,000   22   5.4  19           12           22           18           25           15
39    38            I. Smith  NaN  PG  A  WAS  GSW    8   0.3    1   $5,000   22   4.3  24           26           29           30           12           16
40    39              A. Len  NaN   C  H  SAC  DET    7  -2.4    1   $4,000   21   5.2  20          NaN           16           11           26           24
41    40       B. Bogdanovic  NaN  SG  H  SAC  DET   25  -2.4    1   $5,100   20   4.0  24           16           32           28           23           24
42    41           D. Howard  NaN   C  A  LAL  NOP   29   3.5  B2B   $4,400   20   4.6  22           12           20           15           36           20
43    42             J. Hart  NaN  SG  H  NOP  LAL   22   0.5    1   $4,900   19   4.0  24           20           33           20           17           13
44    43           M. Morris  NaN  PG  H  DEN  TOR   15   0.4    1   $4,600   19   4.2  19           26           12           34           29           18
45    44            R. Rondo  NaN  PG  A  LAL  NOP    4   3.5  B2B   $4,300   19   4.5  19           14           28            7           30           10
46    45        T. Brown Jr.  NaN  SF  A  WAS  GSW   24   0.3    1   $4,400   19   4.3  23           24           17            9           12           24
47    46            T. Davis  NaN  SG  A  TOR  DEN   10  -3.0    1   $4,600   19   4.1  16            3           19           21           20            8
48    47          C. Boucher  NaN  PF  A  TOR  DEN   25  -3.0    1   $4,200   19   4.4  16            4           21           37           20            8
49    48       S. Mykhailiuk  NaN  SG  A  DET  SAC   23  -2.0    1   $3,500   18   5.2  15           13           16            8           10           27
50    49     K. Caldwell-Pop  NaN  SG  A  LAL  NOP    2   3.5  B2B   $4,200   18   4.3  17           19           16           22           20           16
51    50         L. Galloway  NaN  SG  A  DET  SAC   18  -2.0    1   $4,100   18   4.4  17           17           13           26           14           12
52    51      J. Toscano-And  NaN  SF  H  GSW  WAS   11   3.0  B2B   $4,300   18   4.2  18           32           38           13           10           15
53    52            J. Poole  GTD  SG  H  GSW  WAS   18   3.0  B2B   $4,900   18   3.6  15           27           27           20           25          NaN
54    53           K. Looney  NaN   C  H  GSW  WAS   15   3.0  B2B   $3,500   18   5.1  10           12           15           14           16           22
55    54          A. Bradley  NaN  SG  A  LAL  NOP    3   3.5  B2B   $4,000   18   4.4  15           33           10            8           19            8
56    55            T. Snell  NaN  SG  A  DET  SAC   23  -2.0    1   $3,900   17   4.2  15           30           15            9           28           13
...
```