# BeautifulSoup : Unable to find image URL's in for loop

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a website through beautiful soup + selenium and getting their image URLs under `<img>` tag with `src` as an attribute. I don't want to scrape through `div class names`. Here is what i am scraping through:

`<img src="https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/f1fb5ec60129b029e968f0522fe4828c?s=100&amp;d=retro&amp;f=y" alt="" width="55" height="55">`

I want to get all URLs under image tag. Here is my code which is giving me an error:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver

user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) ' \
             'Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36'

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')
options.add_argument("--disable-web-security")
options.add_argument("--allow-running-insecure-content")
options.add_argument("--allow-cross-origin-auth-prompt")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\intel\Downloads\setups\chromedriver.exe", options=options)
driver.get("https://python-forum.io/Thread-Using-beautiful-soup-to-get-html-attribute-value")

page = Soup(driver.page_source, features='html.parser')
divs = page.select("img")
for product in divs:
    ele = divs.find('src') 
    print(ele)
```

**It's giving me attribute error :**

```
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find'. 
You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?
```

Any of your help would be appreciated...

Comment: Can you try changing this `ele = divs.find('src') ` to `ele = divs.find_all('src') `

Comment: Again the same error... @AzyCrw4282

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? That error message seems rather clear to me, no? As an aside, what is the point of using Selenium if you're just going to pass the page source to BeautifulSoup?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Beautiful Soup: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'find\_all'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24108507/beautiful-soup-resultset-object-has-no-attribute-find-all)

Comment: It's just a part of my code. Selenium is for automation tasks. So i can't post my whole 500 lines of code here, so posted a piece only, where the use of selenium seems pretty useless @AMS

Comment: @Minipekka check my answer below. you don't need to use `selenium`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intitaly i thought, this `ele = divs.find('src')` should be `ele = product.find('src')` but that didnt work, so I have implemented in in the following way. Change this

```
page = Soup(driver.page_source, features='html.parser')
divs = page.select("img")
for product in divs:
    ele = divs.find('src') 
    print(ele)
```

to this

```
page = Soup(driver.page_source, features='html.parser')
divs = page.find_all("img")
print(divs)
for product in divs:
    ele = product['src']
    print(ele)
```

This should give you values in the src attribute of the `img` tag.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def main(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    target = [item['content']
              for item in soup.findAll("meta", {'property': "og:image"})]
    print(target)


main("https://python-forum.io/Thread-Using-beautiful-soup-to-get-html-attribute-value")
```

Output:

```
['https://python-forum.io/images/facebook.png', 'https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/f1fb5ec60129b029e968f0522fe4828c?s=100&d=retro&f=y']
```