# Python iteration over table with beautifulsoup gives only first column

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

thanks to many posts on stackoverflow I found many ways to get closer to my solution but it seems like I always have the same problem. I only get the first column of a table

Goal:
[This URL](https://www.wegweiser-kommune.de/statistik/ulm+demographischer-wandel+2006-2018+tabelle) here has only one table, which I'd like to scrape

Here is my code:

```
# 1. get the html doc 
source = requests.get("www.placeholder.com").text

# 2. get the BeautifulSoup object
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

# 3. find the table
find_class = soup.table
tbody_1 = find_class.tbody


n = 1
m = 1
for row in tbody_1.find_all('tr'):
    for col in row.find_all('td'):
        if col == "Tag":
            print(col)
            print(n)
            print(m)
            print("Tags will be passed")
            pass
        else:
            if n < 13:
                value_list = []
                value_list.append(col)
                print(col)
                print(n)
                print(m)
                val_dict[m] = value_list
                n = n+1
                # m = m
            else:
                value_list = []                
                value_list.append(col)
                print(col)
                print(n)
                print(m)
                val_dict[m+1] = value_list
                n = 1
                m = m+1
```

This gave me the problem of:
[Tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AE7mu.png)

Using:

```
value_list.append(col.select('span')[0].get_text())
```

Lead to the problem of:
[First Item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddqmX.png).
Here only the first item of each row was used

Inspiration by (answers in) inter alia [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24108507/beautiful-soup-resultset-object-has-no-attribute-find-all)

```
for row in table.find_all('tr'):
    for col in row.find_all('td'):
```

I'll edit the post when for whatever is needed in addition to what I provided.

Comment: It's *scrape* **not** *scrap*, as *scrap* means to get rid of as no longer of enough worth.

Comment: Thanks, will edit

Comment: And what would your desired output be? The entire table?

Comment: Yes the entire table

Comment: I think I got lost in the many ways of achieving it and somehow didn't get any of them right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you want is the table, then I'd recommend exploring `pandas` and making your (scraping) life easier.

Here's how:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

source_url = "https://www.placeholder.com"
page = requests.get(source_url).text
df = pd.read_html(page, flavor="bs4")
pd.concat(df).to_csv("demographischer_statistik.csv", index=False)
```

This outputs a `.csv` file that looks like this:

[image]

And if you're into so-called `one-liners` the above code can effectively be reduced to:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

pd.concat(pd.read_html(requests.get("https://placeholder.com").text, flavor="bs4")).to_csv("demographischer_statistik.csv", index=False)
```

But that's not too readable, if you ask me. ;)

Comment: Oh man... this is way too easy...

Thanks a lot for the quick reply, this definitely helps a lot

Comment: I will build a loop to go through multiple pages, so the one-liner will be great for other projects but not fitting right here :)