# bs4 can't get specific results

Tags: beautifulsoup

I am trying to get specific data from a website that is under a class that is used multiple times. So my thought was to search for the next biggest class and then use bs4 again to narrow my search results further. However, I get this error:

```
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find_all'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?
```

This is my code:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def main():
    responce()

def responce():
    r = requests.get('https://robinhood.com/stocks/WISH')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    responce = soup.find_all(class_="css-ktio0g""")
    responce = responce.find_all(class_="css-6e9xj2")
    print(responce)

main()
```

Comment: `find_all` is returning a list ! in your case, you've to iterate over it ?, Also specify which data you would like to extract

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Beautiful Soup: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'find\_all'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24108507/beautiful-soup-resultset-object-has-no-attribute-find-all)

Comment: Also once you fix the logic, the 6e9xj2 should be 6e9jx2.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pprint import pp


def main(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    goal = [x.text for x in soup.select('span.css-ktio0g')]
    pp(goal)


main('https://robinhood.com/stocks/WISH')
```

Output:

```
['Piotr Szulczewski',
 '—',
 'San Francisco, California',
 '2010',
 '7.25B',
 '—',
 '—',
 '155.46M',
 '$12.39',
 '$11.44',
 '$11.97',
 '76.70M',
 '$32.85',
 '$7.52',
 '— per share',
 'Expected Aug 11, After Hours',
 'Sign up for a Robinhood Account to buy or sell ContextLogic stock and '
 'options commission-free.']
```

Comment: is there a way to then specify a class within that span? for example that "76.70m" is within a class call "css-css-6e9jx2"